# What's the difference between Javascript Object and JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone tell me the difference between Javascript Object and JSON object with an example?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A Javascript *object* is a data type in Javascript - it makes sense only in Javascript. Often you see a Javascript *object literal* like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
```

---

A JSON *string* is a data interchange format - it is nothing more than a bunch of characters formatted a particular way (in order for different programs to communicate with each other). Because of this, it can exist inside Javascript, or in another language or simply stored inside a database or a text file.

The above Javascript object can be represented in the JSON format in Javascript like this:

```
var json = '{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }';
```

Or in C# like this:

```
string json = "{ \"a\": 1, \"b\": 2 }";
```

As you can see, a JSON is simply stored inside a string. To make it useful, the JSON string can be *parsed* to produce an object in any language. Because the JSON format mimics Javascript's object literal syntax, Javascript makes the parsing process easy:

```
var obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

Though typically you'd see:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json); // for security reasons
```

---

Note that JSON is limited in that it cannot store functions - the only values it can contain are:

- objects (literals)
- arrays
- numbers
- booleans
- strings
- nulls

Comment: The key difference between JSON and Javascript object is "JSON string is a data interchange format" and Javascript object is a data type in Javascript

Answer (score 15):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a text representation of a javscript object. It is effectively an object literal in javascript notation (hence the name - JavaScript Object Notation => JSON).

If you want to "compare" two object, convert the text to objects then compare keys and values.

Some examples of objects to/from text:

```
// Create obj using an object literal
var obj = {key: 'value'};

// Convert to text using JSON.stringify
var text = JSON.stringify(obj);

// Show the value of text
alert( text ); // {"key":"value"}

// Create a new object from text
var newObj = JSON.parse(text); // javascript object

// Show the text version of newObj
alert(JSON.stringify(newObj));  // {"key":"value"}

// Use text as code
var newObj2 = eval('(' + text + ')');

// It is indeed a string literal
alert(JSON.stringify(newObj2));  // {"key":"value"}
```

If you want to compare two objects, convert them from JSON to objects (if they are JSON in the first place) then do something like:

```
function compareObjects(a, b) {
  var i, p, aProps = [], bProps = [];

  // Simple test first
  if (a === b) {
    return true;
  }

  // Get properties of a
  for (p in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      aProps.push(p);
    } 
  }

  // Get properties of b
  for (p in b ) {
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      bProps.push(p);
    } 
  }

  // If don't have same properties, return false
  if (aProps.sort().join('') != bProps.sort().join('')) {
    return false;
  }

  // If property values aren't the same, return false
  i = aProps.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (a[aProps[i]] !== b[bProps[i]]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If passed all tests, must be equal
  return true;
}
```

Comment: yes I have read that..i do not get a declaration example of both anywhere..i want to compare them and see what's different?

Comment: Edit your question to include that.

Comment: Be aware: the "var obj =" is NOT part of JSON! Technically speaking, JSON is data-only although it tends to be executed as if it's code to load an object in memory. You only need the {} and the stuff in-between as JSON data, which you could then 'evaluate' and assign to a variable in your JavaScript code or other programming language. Adding the "var" thing turns JSON into Javascript...

Comment: @Wim - yes, good point. I was using a javascript object literal as an easy way to get a properly formatted JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". Basically, JSON is Javascript, but limited to just filling an object with data. By executing a JSON object, you "load" the data in memory.
JavaScript is the bigger picture, with additional lines of code to manipulate the object or to do all kinds of other stuff.

A JSON example would be this:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A JavaScript example would be this:

```
var Glossary = {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the **var Glossary =** in the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Well First of all a JavaScript is just like any other Object in object oriented programming.

And as RobG said JSON is effectively an object literal in Javascript Notation. But Not exactly.
According to a Javascript book it says this is an object defined by using Object Notation:

```
var newObject = 
{     prop1 : true,     
showMessage : function (msg) {alert(msg)} 
};
```

According to JSON in JavaScript,

JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript.

Also you might want to consider taking a look this [link](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
    name: "John",
    profession: "blogger"
};

alert(object.name);//John
alert(typeof(object));//Object
alert(object);//[object Object]


var json = JSON.stringify(object);

alert(json.name);//undefined
alert(typeof(json));//string
alert(json);//{"name":"John","profession":"blogger"}
```