# Parsing non-standard JSON

Tags: c#, java, javascript, json, string-parsing

Anyone know what type of JSON (if even that!) the following code is? I'm retrieving this from the HTML of a website. I'm trying to parse it in C# with a JSON parser, but I'm having to do lots of preparatory editing to format it as 'valid' JSON according to JSONLint. For example, the names of the variables should all have double quotes rather than having no quotes at all.

```js
{
status: 'A',
displayed: 'Y',
start_time: '2010-11-2600: 00: 00',
start_time_xls: {
    en: '26thofNov201000: 00am',
    es: '26Nov201000: 00am'
},
suspend_at: '2010-11-2619: 57: 59',
is_off: 'Y',
score_home: '',
score_away: '',
bids_status: '',
period_id: '',
curr_period_start_time: '',
score_extra_info: '',
ev_id: 2257335,
blurb: '',
last_mkts_of_day: false,
follow_hcap_mkt: 10999896
}
```

This will always have the same format and I'd love to just parse it straight to an object in C# or java.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a native JS object.

Comment: Looks to me like somebody rolled their own JSON emitter and got the details wrong.

Comment: That's not HTML nor JSON. It's JavaScript (granted, in a HTML script tag).

Comment: JSON-parseable string: http://jsfiddle.net/yb5Pb/

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's an object literal to be precise (since this is source code - JavaScript objects don't exist in the source code but in memory).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Fair enough. Point is it's not a JSON-formatted string.

Comment: A decent primer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON requires that all names be in double quotes, so this is not valid JSON. This is a valid Javascript object. For JSON format questions go here: http://json.org/

It's not totally clear where you want to do this conversion to JSON, but in Javascript you can use `window.JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/3xZD8/

```js
var object = {
    names: {
        en: 'VirtualMarket-2MinuteLevel',
        es: 'VirtualMarket-2MinuteLevel'
    },
    status: 'A',
    displayed: 'Y',
    start_time: '2010-11-2600: 00: 00',
    start_time_xls: {
        en: '26thofNov201000: 00am',
        es: '26Nov201000: 00am'
    },
    suspend_at: '2010-11-2619: 57: 59',
    is_off: 'Y',
    score_home: '',
    score_away: '',
    bids_status: '',
    period_id: '',
    curr_period_start_time: '',
    score_extra_info: '',
    ev_id: 2257335,
    blurb: '',
    last_mkts_of_day: false,
    follow_hcap_mkt: 10999896
    },
    json = window.JSON.stringify( object );
```

Comment: Any solution? Maybe this would be better off as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse your input string. You can even make use of `dynamic` as below with the help of [this extension class](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA) (Tested with your string)

```
dynamic obj = JsonUtils.JsonObject.GetDynamicJsonObject(jsonstr);
Console.WriteLine(obj.names.en);
Console.WriteLine(obj.status);
Console.WriteLine(obj.start_time_xls.en);
Console.WriteLine(obj.suspend_at);
```

With pure Json.Net

```
JObject jObj =  (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json3);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["names"]["en"]);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["status"]);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["start_time_xls"]["en"]);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["suspend_at"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not (I vote “not”) it's valid:

- Read in the string;
- `s {^\s*([a-z0-9_]+)\:} {"\1":} g`

seems to work for this data set, and I'll bet that they're just `strcat`ting the output at you, so it's probably safe for the time being.

Comment: I just ran it through Perl on my laptop; but it's meant to simply enquote the "key" values -- you probably (in C#) would do something where you pass the two {}-expressions into a "search" and "replace" method ... without the braces. (My phone can't type the caret or backslash, but copy from caret to : and possibly add extra backslashes before the backslashes and double quotes)

Comment: Now that I'm in front of a real keyboard, I believe the C# syntax would be `Regex.Replace (json_string, "^\\s*(<l>[a-z0-9_]+)\\:", "\"${l}\"");` (using `<l>` as a named tag for “label” and `${l}` rather than `\1` to refer back to it)