# How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, code-generation

Given the following JSON object,

```
form = {
  "name": "",
  "address": {
    "street": "",
    "city": "",
    "province": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "country": ""
  },
  "phoneDay": "",
  "phoneCell": "",
  "businessName": "",
  "website": "",
  "email": ""
}
```

what is a tool to auto-generate the following C# class?

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneDay { get; set; }
    public string PhoneCell { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

We have already looked at these questions:

[Generate C# classes from JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358745/generate-c-sharp-classes-from-json-schema) Is asking about JSON Schemas which may be an approach to use down the road.

[Benefits and drawbacks of generated C# classes for Json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229237/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-generated-c-sharp-classes-for-json-objects)

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ ???

Comment: try this tool might help.. http://tools4geeks.com/json-to-Csharp-classes

Comment: Anyone know how to do this same thing with Swagger YAML?

Comment: Unfortunately json2charp.com is now a domain on sale. That sucks, and the quicktipe one is kinda clunky. Does anybody know a better alternative?

Comment: @DARKGuy jsonutils https://jsonutils.com/

Comment: json2sharp is live as of this morning.....

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Five options:

- Use the free [jsonutils](https://jsonutils.com/) web tool without installing anything.
- If you have [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class.
- Use the free [jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/downloads/get/631627).exe
- The web tool [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) does not require installing anything.
- The web tool [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) also does not require installing anything.

Pros and Cons:

- [jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/downloads/get/631627) converts to PascalCase but the others do not.
- [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) has some logic to recognize dictionaries and handle JSON properties whose names are invalid c# identifiers.

Comment: both Web Essentials and json2csharp are doing a great job. Didn't try jsonclassgenerator, cause it seemed like a hassle to need to open a separate app just for that

Comment: I haven't tried jsonclassgenerator but I can see the advantage. For example if you had a mock api, you could interate over a set of endpoints to regenerate your models. You could go as far as setting a script that checks for new commits and updates the model if anything has changed. You wouldn't want to manually paste new json each time as this could be prone to mistakes.

Comment: The json2csharp tool does a nicer job than VS of formatting the classes especially the class names.  It will remove ambiguous characters like "_" and correctly camel case the class names thereafter.

Comment: "jsonutils" is pretty cool, it can generate attributes like "Json properties" as well, http://jsonutils.com/

Comment: app.quicktype.io  this one does not work on some machines due to security concerns.

Answer (score 174):

Visual Studio 2012 (with ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 RC installed) supports this [natively](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx).

Visual Studio 2013 onwards have this built-in.

[image: Visual Studio Paste JSON as Classes screenshot]
*(Image courtesy: [robert.muehsig](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/))*

Comment: I think this solution is the best, because you will not need an external program!

Comment: before pasting [here](http://superuser.com/questions/777213/copy-json-from-console-log-in-developer-tool-to-clipboard) is **solution to Copy JSON from console.log** in developer tool to clipboard. Hope helps.

Answer (score 12):

If you install Web Essentials into Visual studio you can go to Edit => Past special => paste JSON as class.

That is probably the easiest there is.

Web Essentials: http://vswebessentials.com/