# asp.net MVC Serialize model with properties/attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize the model with properties/attributes. But I'm unable to do the properties. How to serialize model with attributes?

Model:

```
   [Display(Name = "CreateCustomerView_FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DomainName")]
    [Display(Name = "CreateCustomerView_LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Controller: 
Serialization:

```
  cookie.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel);
  //var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //cookie.Value = serializer.Serialize(viewModel);

            //cookie.Value = viewModel.ToString();
```

Deserialization:

```
 viewModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<viewModel>(Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what your asking. When you serialize a model it creates a name/value pair for each property in the model. When you deserialize, it converts that back to the model (which has the attributes).

Comment: If i understand you correctly, this might give you a clue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string