# Is it possible to extract the JSON schema from a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a bunch of JSON strings, and would like to identify the schema of each one. This will allow me to keep a count of the different types of JSON objects in my collection of JSON strings.

I do not know the structure of these JSON strings ahead of time, and thus do not have a PONO to try to deserialize to.

I am currently using `json.net`, but am open to other options.

Comment: Have you tried deserializing into a dynamic?  You can deserialize into a dynamic and re-serialize that into a string as well.

Comment: You have a common property in all but difrentes values ​​by type of json ?

Comment: well, I know a way to generate it: not directly but.. you can convert the json file to c# class first:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string

and then convert the class into json schema:
https://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/using-json-net-to-generate-jsonschema/


Not the neatest solution but yeah it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use NJsonSchema for that, 
see https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator

Answer (score 0):

Previously JSchema was in JSON.NET Library but now its deprecated and they moved it to another library .. You Can Use **[Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)** ..It will easily Give You Schema of Any JSON String..even You Can Parse any JSON Using this Lib. ..like Suppose You Have JSON String ie _strJSON

```
JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(_strJSON);
```