# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a Json file as shown below. I want to convert only the  **option** node in the JSON file into a C# **ListItemCollection** object

ASP.net File:

```
   var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/json.json");
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path,false))
    {                      
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        ListItemCollection licRB = new ListItemCollection();  
        licRB = arr.AnswerRadioButton.option;<<-- run time error is produced here 
    }
```

JSON File:

```
{   "FormTitle": "This is Form Title from JSON",
  "TitleQuestion1": "This is the Title of Question 1",
  "TextQuestion1": "1- This is the text of Quextion Number 1",
  "AnswerRadioButton": {
"visible": "true",
"title": "Radio Button Title",
"FieldsetRBStyle": { "border": "1px" },
"option" : [
  {
    "text": "text1",
    "value": "v1",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "text": "text2",
    "value": "v2",
    "checked": "true"
  },
  {
    "text": "text3",
    "value": "v3",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "text": "text4",
    "value": "v4",
    "checked": "true"
  }
]  }}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ChangeTo(arr.AnswerRadioButton.option, TypeOf(ListViewCollection))`? You might need to do it on a per-item basis if that fails. Basically, you cannot cast dynamic types unless they fit certain condition, but you can convert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the required classes (e.g. using [this](http://json2csharp.com/) tool) you can access the options like this:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var options = test.AnswerRadioButton.option;
```

Comment: is there a way to generate class from JSON file  on run time instead of using this tool

Comment: -- Yes I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string