# Can we create a MVC model from an HTML form

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am rendering html from database on a page. For each form I want to provide a button, clicking which can add a table to my database with exactly same fields in form. Is it possible to do so?

I have attached screenshot of how my page looks like now.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Everything is possible if you try hard enough :-)

Comment: I do not understand the question ... You have to send a fragment of the form and handle it on the server side. (for example by: AJAX, html FORM split, submit button name)

Comment: @bato3 by clicking CREATE label on my page[as in screenshot] , i want to create model from form.

Comment: so use ajax to send to server form part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First you should have a form markup on front-end.

You should bind your data to your form inputs.

Then you should have a `submit` function, which collects data, then (optionally) prepares it, and then sends it (with form id) via `POST` request to server.

**EDIT**

> If you need just to access the view (document) and cut the part from it.
>   You can use, for example, `document.getElementDyId` or other dom access method. So you'll have html data in js var, which can be sent to server. Next moment is to parse html to fields-containing json, it can be done either before or after sending to server.

Server should handle form type and fields to create model.

If you need a solution to make class from json, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string)

Comment: Is there any possible way to not fill the data in form but directly clicking a button can prepare model from HTML(i am saving html in database and then rendering on this page in loop).

Comment: If html has all needed data for model - yes, of course.
You should just prepare proper js object on submit.

Comment: I know how to create model from JSON , here i am talking about html . Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: you should 
1) take it from dom
2) parse it to json

Comment: @deepak see edit

Comment: Yes , it looks like, will work. I am going to try this. Thanks @Eugene Mihaylin

Comment: And if the data in html is data in your 1st db,
you can add a dictionary {form_id : [/*form_fields*/]}.

Then clicking on the CREATE will only send form_id to server.

And server can get fields from dictionary.

So you'll make less moves and avoid parcing.

Comment: please upvote and pick answer if it will help you

Comment: Yeah right , it is very helpful. thanks.

Comment: @deepak please pick answer

Comment: The steps you told me to follow , inspired me . I first converted my html string from database to xml , then i converted it to json object and added elements to list.I am selecting your answer.Thanks