# Error in VB.NET JSON POST request - HTTPWEBREQUEST

Tags: json, vb.net

i am trying to post json request as following.

I am getting an error on last line. Error message shown at last line.

```
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
Dim myResp1 As HttpWebResponse

myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pro.mastersindia.co/oauth/access_token")
myReq.Method = "POST"
myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
myReq.Headers.Add("username", Service_Provider_Username)
myReq.Headers.Add("password", Service_Provider_Password)
myReq.Headers.Add("client_id", client_id)
myReq.Headers.Add("client_secret", client_secret)
myReq.Headers.Add("grant_type", "password")

Dim mystream As Stream = myReq.GetRequestStream
myResp = myReq.GetResponse  ---- here i am getting an error  {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
```

---

if i send same json to same url via POSTMAN then i do get response.
But via vb.net code, i am getting above error.

Am i missing something or doing anything wrong ?

Pls help.

Thanks

[ Following is working in postman, am i missing something in vb.net doing same]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8znO.png)

---

[image]

Comment: What are you POSTing? I see that you are adding things to headers but not to the body for post. Also, where are you sending json objects as you would using postman?

Comment: this is just to get auth_token from service provider.

Comment: i added postman screenshot, which works, but vb.net is not working.

Comment: You hsould look at this it shows you how to send json over vb.net: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384534/how-to-post-a-json-to-a-specific-url-using-vb-net

Comment: In Postman you are putting everything in the body, while in VB you are putting everything in headers. Refer to the site’s specifications for what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8) example to do a POST.

Comment: i added specification sent by service provider. i am new to json in vb.net, so pls help with the code. thanks

Comment: @shahkalpesh i tried to understand the link which you sent. But it point to specifically content type property only. I could not resolve it.

Comment: @dsd7a7, how do i put in body then in vb.net. I also updated my question with specification provided by service provider. Hopefully it can help this forum to understand and help me.

Comment: You may need to do the following to set the body `ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding (); byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes (postData); myReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length; Stream newStream = myReq.GetRequestStream ();  newStream.Write (byte1, 0, byte1.Length);`. You may have to use UTF8Encoding instead of ASCIIEncoding & you will need to create a json string of the key/value you are adding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565130/how-can-i-create-json-on-the-fly-in-an-easier-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POST body is empty, you are supposed to put those into body not headers.

There are multiple ways to do it, here is one example.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

    Public Class JSON_Post
        Public Property username As String
        Public Property password As String
        Public Property client_id As String
        Public Property client_secret As String
        Public Property grant_type As String
    End Class


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pro.mastersindia.co/oauth/access_token")
        myReq.Method = "POST"
        myReq.ContentType = "application/json"

        Dim NewData As New JSON_Post
        NewData.username = "Service_Provider_Username"
        NewData.password = "Service_Provider_Password"
        NewData.client_id = "client_id"
        NewData.client_secret = "client_secret"
        NewData.grant_type = "password"

        Dim PostString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewData)
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostString)
        myReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

        Dim dataStream As Stream = myReq.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close() 'sends request

        Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()

    End Sub
```

Your body then looks like:

```
{"username":"Service_Provider_Username","password":"Service_Provider_Password","client_id":"client_id","client_secret":"client_secret","grant_type":"password"}
```