# Newtonsoft Json parse with different object names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Currently, I am trying to parse some JSON I receive from an API. Here are some results I get back:

```
{
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cannonball",
        "members": true,
        "sp": 5,
        "buy_average": 152,
        "buy_quantity": 358914,
        "sell_average": 151,
        "sell_quantity": 778131,
        "overall_average": 152,
        "overall_quantity": 1137045
    },
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Cannon base",
        "members": true,
        "sp": 187500,
        "buy_average": 184833,
        "buy_quantity": 9,
        "sell_average": 180518,
        "sell_quantity": 10,
        "overall_average": 182562,
        "overall_quantity": 19
    }
}
```

I need to parse it to a C# class. I tried copying the JSON and with paste special converting it to a class, but then it creates an class for every JSON object.

Does someone have any tips on how I can parse it so it's only 1 class? The properties are always the same, it is just the object `"2":` that is the problem.

Comment: The way your JSON is structured I think you definitely want it to parse to an `IEnumerable<YourClass>` specifically because the properties are the same. Why do you want this to come in as one class with duplicate keys? At the end of the day you're just creating a class that pretends to be a List.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string)

Comment: @Liam I don't think that's a useful dupe here, OP is basically there, but is stuck with the dynamic property names.

Comment: @Liam I disagree. Not the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to deserialise to a `Dictionary` of your class type. For example:

```
public class Thing 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Members { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

And now you would deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Thing>>(json);
```

Note: you could probably use `Dictionary<int, Thing>` here if it's guaranteed to be numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON you provided consists of two objects, not one. You can parse it into a Dictionary with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, YourClass>>(jsonString)`. You will then have a dictionary with two entries, with keys `2` and `6`.