# Using JsonConvert i dont have any result

Tags: c#, json, json.net, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a Json stream from API to a Object, i try also to convert in a List but the result it's the same.

screenshot of the problem
https://prnt.sc/po3osq

this is the json
    [{"time":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","count":1}]

this the code

```
public class Mezzo
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetBus
    {
        public List<Mezzo> Bus { get; set; }
    }
    public String GetListBus()
    {
        var addr = "http://192.168.43.131:3000/getBus";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(addr);

        request.Method = "GET";
        var content = string.Empty;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetBus>>(content);

                    Debug.WriteLine(details);

                    return "ciao";
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your error?As i understand  you received null in detail object?

Comment: Your JSON corresponds to a `List<Mezzo>` not `List<GetBus>`.  Deserialize it as such: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mezzo>>(content);`   See: [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this already. It works.

```
string json = "[{\"time\":\"1970 - 01 - 01T00: 00:00.000Z\",\"count\":1}]";
var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mezzo>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(details);
```