# How to deserialize encapsulated table of objects in .NET Core from JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I want to retrieve a collection of football leagues from an external api. The response from the server comes as shown below:

```
{
"api": {
    "results": 1496,
    "leagues": [
        {
            "league_id": 1,
            .....
```

The returned object constists of an "api" field which hold "results" and "leagues". I would like deserialize the code and map it to League class objects in my code.

```
var jsonString = await ExecuteUrlAsync(filePath, url);

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<LeagueEntity>>(jsonString);
```

jsonString is correct, but when the program hits second line I get an exception:

> `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable".`

I need to get to the "leagues" field in JSON file, and ignore the rest of the response. How to achieve that?

Comment: Is it `Syste.Text.Json` or `Json.NET` api? How does `LeagueEntity` look like?

Comment: post a complete json sample and i could tell you how to do it with strongly typed model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `LeagueEntity` corresponds to the `api.leagues[*]` objects, you can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) to pick out and deserialize the interesting portions of the JSON:

```
var leagues = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, 
                                                   new { api = new { leagues = default(List<LeagueEntity>) } })
    ?.api?.leagues;
```

This avoids the need to create an explicit data model for the `api.leagues` container objects.  It should also be more efficient than pre-loading into a `JToken` hierarchy, then as a second step selecting and deserializing the `api.leagues` array.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0LisVk).

(Alternatively, you could auto-generate a complete data model for the entire JSON using one of the answers from *[How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182)*.)