# Display Nested List in JSON in Blazor Component

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, blazor

I have a blazor component that executes a GET request to a MongoDB instance. The return value includes a JSON with a nested list like this

```
{
    "id": "5fd4c3e8693957ddf08a2835",
    "name": "Team 1",
    "location": "Test Building",
    "type": "Staff",
    "teamMembers": [
        "5fd4c3f6693957ddf08a2836",
        "5fd4c408693957ddf08a2837",
        "5fd4c418693957ddf08a2838"
    ],
    "teamMemberList": [
        {
            "id": "5fd4c3f6693957ddf08a2836",
            "name": "John Smith",
            "position": "Tech Lead",
            "role": "Team Leader"
        },
        {
            "id": "5fd4c408693957ddf08a2837",
            "name": "Joe Snuffy",
            "position": "Network Admin",
            "role": "Team Member"
        },
        {
            "id": "5fd4c418693957ddf08a2838",
            "name": "Jose Snuffy",
            "position": "Network Admin",
            "role": "Team Member"
        }
    ]
}
```

The GET request is executed using this function

```
private async Task GetTeamInfo(string id)
    {
        teamIdList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Team>>($"api/team/{id}");
    }
```

How do I display only the teamMemberList information in a table like this?

```
                                <table class='table'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Rank</th>
                                            <th>Role</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@teammember.Name</td>
                                                <td>@teammember.Rank</td>
                                                <td>@teammember.Role</td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                               </table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your root JSON value is an object not an array so deserializing that JSON to `List<Team>` will not work.   You will need to create an appropriate root data model to deserialize your JSON.  [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) has a variety of tools that can do it automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I actually just solved this and you were exactly right! Add as answer and I will credit!