# Accessing Nested Array in JSON in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, json, .net

thank you in advance for your contributions.  I am passing a JSON string to a .NET controller and parsing it in a C# class.  Here is my JSON..

```
{"CusEmail":"foo-bar@gmail.com","Name":"Foo Bar",
    "Items":[{"ItemId":1234,"ItemDesc":"Item-1234"},{"ItemId":5678,"ItemDesc":"Item-5678"}]
}
```

Here is a snippet of my C# class defining the JSON variables (not including the nested array).

```
public class CreateOrderRequest
{
    public string CusEmail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is a snippet of my C# class that is parsing the JSON

```
 public JsonResult CreateShipTo(CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest)
 {
       ... parsing code here
 }
```

Currently, all of this code works but now I need to access that nested array "Items" in the JSON.  How do I declare that correctly in the code above?  I tried Array but that did not work.

Comment: Use one of the tools from [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) to generate a data model for you.  You will need to add a `public List<Item> Items { get; set; }` to `CreateOrderRequest` where `Item` looks like `public class Item { public long ItemId { get; set; } public string ItemDesc { get; set; } }`.

Comment: `I tried Array but that did not work` - Can you include what you tried? How did it not work? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A List will work:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
}

public class WithItems
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```