# How to get the value of text node from json using c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

{"language":"en","textAngle":0.0,"orientation":"Up","regions":[{"boundingBox":"7,7,476,264","lines":[{"boundingBox":"7,7,476,58","words":[{"boundingBox":"7,7,42,44","text":"If"},{"boundingBox":"62,16,283,49","text":"computers"},{"boundingBox":"361,9,122,45","text":"can't"}]},{"boundingBox":"7,77,451,57","words":[{"boundingBox":"7,77,149,56","text":"adapt"},{"boundingBox":"172,77,155,57","text":"easily,"},{"boundingBox":"338,79,120,43","text":"then"}]},{"boundingBox":"8,146,460,57","words":[{"boundingBox":"8,146,178,56","text":"maybe"},{"boundingBox":"201,147,82,44","text":"the"},{"boundingBox":"299,148,169,55","text":"people"}]},{"boundingBox":"7,214,414,57","words":[{"boundingBox":"7,214,145,57","text":"using"},{"boundingBox":"166,216,137,43","text":"them"},{"boundingBox":"318,231,103,29","text":"can."}]}]}]}

i need the output like the below. could someone provide snippet for this as i am new to json

text: if
text: computers
text: can't
text: adapt

Comment: use NewtonSoft jsonConvert and convert text to c# Model

Comment: And [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) to design an appropriate c# model.