# Convert String representing class to Dynamic in C#

Tags: .net

I have a Textbox, and will contaiing Class Definition.

It will be like this:

[image: form]

How to convert string inside textbox to dynamic Object?

What library is exist?

I am trying to find this but just finding not match case like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70657285/generate-class-defintion-from-dynamic-object) which is more similar

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roslyn_(compiler)

Comment: Exellent, Hans!... I found it finally 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis