# How to correctly deserialize nested object in array with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm facing this json data:

```
{
    "pagemeta": {
        "slug": "/",
        "title": "test",
        "description": "test"
    },
    "navigationlinks": {
        "links": [{
            "navigationlink": {
                "name": "Index.",
                "url": "/"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

And both using `HttpRespondeMessage.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<T>();` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, new MyClassToDeserializeInto())`
Both parsings seem to function well, except when it comes to the objects inside the array `"links"`.

Those do get to become object in the array in class but all data is `null`(both `name` and `url` like in this example).

Am I doing something wrong to don't get the json deserialized correctly?

Following are the classes that I use as the final target object:

**HomeData.cs**

```
public sealed class HomeData
    {
        [JsonProperty("pagemeta")]
        public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("navigationlinks")]
        public NavigationLinks NavigationLinks { get; set; }
    }
```

**NavigationLinks.cs**

```
public class NavigationLinks
    {
        [JsonProperty("links")]
        public NavigationLink[] Links { get; set; }
    }
```

**NavigationLink.cs**

```
public class NavigationLink
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

meanwhile the `PageMeta.cs` does the data correctly.

Comment: Your data model is not correct.  Upload your JSON to one of the tools suggested in [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) such as https://json2csharp.com/ or https://app.quicktype.io/ and you will get a correct data model.

Comment: As shown by those tools you need an extra level of container with a `"navigationlink"` property, e.g. `public partial class Navigationlinks {  [JsonProperty("links")] public Link[] Links { get; set; } }` which contains the extra level  **`public partial class Link { [JsonProperty("navigationlink")] public Navigationlink Navigationlink { get; set; } }`**

Comment: I copied the auto-generated classes from https://json2csharp.com/ into https://dotnetfiddle.net/UKxxpB and your JSON can be deserialized successfully.  json2csharp does the same thing as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591919/3744182) by [user3026017](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3026017/user3026017), which is to add an extra level of object with a `public Navigationlink Navigationlink { get; set; }` property.  Closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the Links class, and mark the Links class as JsonObject

```
public sealed class HomeData
{
    [JsonProperty("pagemeta")]
    public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("navigationlinks")]
    public NavigationLinks NavigationLinks { get; set; }
}

public class PageMeta
{
    [JsonProperty("slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationLink
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationLinks
{
    [JsonProperty("links")]
    public Links[] Links { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class Links
{
    [JsonProperty("navigationlink")]
    public NavigationLink NavigationLink { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like this :

```
var homedata = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(text, new HomeData());
```

Comment: But Links isn't a jsonObject it's a jsonArray

Comment: NavigationLinks contains the array of Links..