# Print Json object using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to return this json response

```
{
    "Type": "testing",
    "Errors": {
        "InputOne": [
            "The input one is accepted"
        ],
        "InputTwo": [
            "The input two is accepted"
        ]
    }
}
```

But after trying a few rounds all I got was this

```
{
    "Type": "testing",
    "Errors": {
        "InputOne": "The input one is accepted",
        "InputTwo": "The input two is accepted"
    }
}
```

May I know what am I missing here?

These are my code

```
public string Type { get; set; }
public ErrorClass Errors { get; set; }

public class ErrorClass
{
  public object InputOne { get; set; }
  public object InputTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing they are both strings instead of arrays/lists/collections of strings!

Comment: you need an array/list in ErrorClass like  public List<object> InputOne { get; set; }

Comment: You can create classes directly from demo json -f.e. https://codewithoutcomplaint.com/how-to-generate-a-c-class-from-json-in-visual-studio-2019/ - no need to "try a few rounds"  or  [how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-string)

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you for your suggestion to look at the auto generate a c sharp file from json! It helps alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public string Type { get; set; }
public ErrorClass Errors { get; set; }

public class ErrorClass
{
  public string[] InputOne { get; set; }
  public string[] InputTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your help nicola
I also eventually found out after @patrickartner comment of generating a c sharp class file from json
Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You need to return a list/collection/array of **InputOne** and **InputTwo** according to your response.

```
public string Type { get; set; }
public ErrorClass Errors { get; set; }

public class ErrorClass
{
   public List<object> InputOne { get; set; }
 public List<object> InputTwo { get; set; }
}
```