# How to deserialize the neston JSON array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to read my nested JSON result and I'm able to read the data from the first array. But not able to read from the remaining.

**BELOW IS THE CODE WHICH GIVES THE RESULT FROM THE ORDER NODE**

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/biXBqd

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    string json = @"{""orders"": [
    {
        ""orderNumber"": ""12345"",
        ""orderDate"": ""2022-03-16"",
        ""status"": ""Completed"",
        ""state"": ""Completed"",
        ""description"": """",
        ""subs"": [
            {
                ""subsNumber"": ""54321"",
                ""Managed"": null,
                ""customFields"": {},
                ""FirstVersion"": null,
                ""LastVersion"": 1,
                ""Actions"": [
                    {
                        ""id"": ""abc"",
                        ""sequence"": 0,
                        ""TDates"": [
                            {
                                ""Date"": ""2022-03-16""
                            },
                            {
                                ""Date"": ""2022-03-16""
                            },
                            {
                                ""Date"": ""2022-03-16""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        ""customFields"": {
            ""OrderDelivery"": null,
            ""DateOrderDelivered"": null
        }
    }
],
""nextPage"": ""/orders?page=4"",
""success"": true
}";
    ArrayList profileAry1 = new ArrayList();
    JObject jsonparsing1 = JObject.Parse(json);
    JObject jsonparsing = JObject.Parse(json);
    var token = (JArray)jsonparsing.SelectToken("orders");
    List<string> AuthorList = new List<string>();
    
    foreach (orders orders in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<orders>>(token.ToString()))
                {
                    string orderNumber = orders.orderNumber.ToString();
                    string orderDate = orders.orderDate.ToString();
                    string status = orders.status.ToString();
                    string state = orders.state.ToString();
                    string description = orders.description.ToString();
        
                    Console.WriteLine("Order Number: " + orderNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("Order Number: " + orderDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + status);
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + state);
                    Console.WriteLine("description: " + description);
                    Console.WriteLine();
    }
    PocoCourse items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PocoCourse>(json);
    
    Console.WriteLine("success: " + items.Success);
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + items.nextPage);    
    //Console.WriteLine("Number of Types: " + items.orders.Count);
}
}
public class PocoCourse
{
public bool Success { get; set; }
public string nextPage { get; set; }
public List<orders> orders { get; set; }
}
public class orders
{
public string orderNumber { get; set; }
public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public string state { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }
public List<subs> subs { get; set; }

}
public class subs
{
[JsonProperty("subs")]
public string subsNumber { get; set; }
public string Managed { get; set; }
public string FirstVersion { get; set; }
public string LastVersion { get; set; }
//public List<subscriptions1> subscriptions { get; set; }
public List<List<object>> Points { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the values from subs,Actions and TDates as well which I'm not able to achive.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Have you tried with `orders.subs` inside your for loop? You can read that value.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I have added the fiddle link above which has the code, which I have written.

Comment: I can access `orders.subs` in your fiddle and read its values

Comment: I'm new to coding, I think I'm missing something. Could you please share that part of code with me? So that I will understand how to access orders.subs.

Comment: @Balastrong I have tried again, still not understanding how to read the values from orders.subs.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Are you asking *How to loop through `orders.subs`*?  If so see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IOBGZV.  As an aside, you need to remove `[JsonProperty("subs")]` from `public string subsNumber { get; set; }`.  But your data model `subs` doesn't really match the JSON shown, is that your real problem? If so see [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) for tools to auto-generate a better model.

Comment: I was asking how to loop through orders.subs and it is working as expected now. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to get list of dates for example

```
Data data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json); 

List<DateTime> dates = data.Orders[0].Subs[0].Actions[0].Dates.Select(d => d.Date ).ToList();
```

result

```
    2022-03-16
    2022-03-16
    2022-03-16
```

or actions

```
List<Action> actions = data.Orders[0].Subs[0].Actions.ToList(); 

//or since you have only one

Action action = data.Orders[0].Subs[0].Actions.FirstOrDefault();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "sequence": 0,
    "TDates": [
      {
        "Date": "2022-03-16T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Date": "2022-03-16T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Date": "2022-03-16T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

or if you need only selected values you can do it without creating any classes. For example you can get list of dates

```
var jsonParsed= JObject.Parse(json);

List<DateTime> dates = jsonParsed["orders"][0]["subs"][0]["Actions"][0]["TDates"]
.Select(d => (DateTime) d["Date"]).ToList();
```

classes

```
    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("orders")]
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nextPage")]
        public string NextPage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Order
    {
        [JsonProperty("orderNumber")]
        public long OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("orderDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset OrderDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("subs")]
        public List<Sub> Subs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customFields")]
        public OrderCustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OrderCustomFields
    {
        [JsonProperty("OrderDelivery")]
        public object OrderDelivery { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DateOrderDelivered")]
        public object DateOrderDelivered { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Sub
    {
        [JsonProperty("subsNumber")]
        public long SubsNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Managed")]
        public object Managed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customFields")]
        public SubCustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FirstVersion")]
        public object FirstVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("LastVersion")]
        public long LastVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Actions")]
        public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Action
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sequence")]
        public long Sequence { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TDates")]
        public List<TDate> Dates { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TDate
    {
        [JsonProperty("Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SubCustomFields
    {
    }
```

Comment: Will try this. Thank you for your help.