# Can I get the array of string for ExternalRateID using SelectToken?

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

Here is my JSON which I have parsed to a JObject. Can I get the string array for `ExternalRateId` from the below using `SelectToken`?

As of now, I'm using `foreach()` to loop through and get the list of them and converting it to a string. Can we solve this in much easier way using `SelectToken()`. If so please show me the best way to do this.

```json
{
    "RateCards": [
        {
            "ExternalRateCardId": "62283ab4",
            "Rates": [
                {
                    "ExternalRateId": "2a77db10",
                }
            ],
            "IsUpdate": false
        },
        {
            "ExternalRateCardId": "f6878b23",
            "Rates": [
                {
                    "ExternalRateId": "2a739550",
                }
            ],
            "IsUpdate": false
        },
        {
            "ExternalRateCardId": "3f51162c",
            "Rates": [
                {
                    "ExternalRateId": "2a751bf0",
                }
            ],
            "IsUpdate": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the 'jquery' tag is an error here given your mention of JObject and SelectToken...?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *get the string array for `ExternalRateId`*?  There is an outer array `RateCards` and an inner array `ExternalRateId`, what exactly do you want?  a `string [][]` jagged array?  a `string []` array with the inner array flattened?  Something else? If you could [edit] your question to share your current code that would help to clarify.  See [ask].

Comment: Assuming c#, then rather than manually parsing to `JObject` you could just auto-generate a data model using one of the tools from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182). See https://dotnetfiddle.net/8CBqYc.  Or if you are not allowed to define a data model for some reason, you can use a JSONPath wildcard e.g. like so: `jObject.SelectTokens("RateCards[*].Rates[*].ExternalRateId").Select(r => (string)r).ToArray();`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/wehpOx.  But it's not clear what your requirements are, so please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LINQ

```
List<string> externalRateIds = ((JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["RateCards"])
        .SelectMany(x => x["Rates"].Select(x => (string)x["ExternalRateId"]))
        .ToList();
```

or if you want a weird syntax with SelectToken

```
string[] externalRateIds = ((JArray)JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("RateCards"))
 .SelectMany(x => x.SelectToken("Rates")
 .Select(x => x.SelectToken("ExternalRateId").Value<string>())
.ToArray();
```