# object list inside a List is getting null in the response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponse

i am creating a netcore web api and i need a List of Menus, that menus someones have a submenu list. inside a C# the submenu lists are working fine, but in the response the lists are empty objects

this is my UserService (in this class i make the call to database):

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = null;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    public UserService(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }
   
    public List<MenuResponse> GetMenu(RequestByUser model, IConfiguration Configuration) {
        

        ClassicConnection conn = new ClassicConnection(Configuration);

        SqlConnection conecction = conn.ConnectionLocal();

        List<MenuResponse> lMenuResponse = new List<MenuResponse>();
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("The database has been opened!");
            Console.WriteLine("Connection State: " + conecction.State.ToString());


            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("", conecction);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.P_GetMenu";
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", model.userName));
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 15;
            //sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MenuResponse menuResponse = new MenuResponse();
                menuResponse.tmus_Username = reader.GetString(0);
                menuResponse.tmap_App_ID = reader.GetString(1);
                menuResponse.tmar_Role_ID = reader.GetString(2);
                menuResponse.tmar_Role_Desc = reader.GetString(3);
                menuResponse.tmar_Role_Ref = reader.GetString(4);
                menuResponse.tmar_Role_Icon = reader.GetString(5);
                menuResponse.subMenuText = reader.GetString(6);
                try
                {
                    if (reader.GetString(6) != "") {              
                            menuResponse.subMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubMenu>>(reader.GetString(6));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    menuResponse.subMenuText = ex.Message;
                }
                lMenuResponse.Add(menuResponse);
            }
           


            conecction.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("The database has been closed!");

            conecction.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("The database connection has been disposed!");
            Console.WriteLine("Connection State: " + conecction.State.ToString());
            return lMenuResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

in WsController i make the response of the API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
//[Authorize]
public class WsController : ControllerBase
{
    public static IWebHostEnvironment _enviroment;
    private static IConfiguration Configuration;
    private IUserService _userService;
   
    public WsController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration _configuration, IUserService userService) { 
        _enviroment = environment;
        Configuration = _configuration;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    
    [HttpPost("GetMenu")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetMenu([FromBody] RequestByUser userName) {
        Response response = new Response();
        List<MenuResponse> lMenuResponses = _userService.GetMenu(userName, Configuration);
        if (lMenuResponses.Count == 0) {
            response.done = 0;
            response.msj = "Error!";
            return BadRequest();
        }
        //var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lMenuResponses);
        return Ok(lMenuResponses);
    }
}
```

this is my MenuResponse class :

```
    public class MenuResponse
    {
        public string tmus_Username { get; set; }
        public string tmap_App_ID { get; set; }
        public string tmar_Role_ID { get; set; }
        public string tmar_Role_Desc { get; set; }
        public string tmar_Role_Ref { get; set; }
        public string tmar_Role_Icon { get; set; }
        public string subMenuText { get; set; }
        public List<SubMenu> subMenu { get; set; }
     
    }
```

SubMenu Class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SubMenu
    {
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_ID;
        public string? TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID;
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Desc;
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Ref;
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Status;
        
    }
}
```

in this time am getting a object array like this (the submenu lists are empty objects but the number of registers are correct):

```
[
    {
        "tmus_Username": "epirsch",
        "tmap_App_ID": "COSY",
        "tmar_Role_ID": "C1",
        "tmar_Role_Desc": "ORDERS INFO",
        "tmar_Role_Ref": "OrdersInfo",
        "tmar_Role_Icon": "list",
        "subMenuText": "",
        "subMenu": null
    },
    {
        "tmus_Username": "epirsch",
        "tmap_App_ID": "COSY",
        "tmar_Role_ID": "C2",
        "tmar_Role_Desc": "TRANSPORT",
        "tmar_Role_Ref": "",
        "tmar_Role_Icon": "truck",
        "subMenuText": "[{\"TMRP_Privilege_ID\":\"P10\",\"TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID\":\"C2\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Desc\":\"Transport Creating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Ref\":\"TransportCreate\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Icon\":\"plus\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Status\":\"ON\"},{\"TMRP_Privilege_ID\":\"P11\",\"TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID\":\"C2\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Desc\":\"Transport Updating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Ref\":\"TransportUpdating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Icon\":\"pen\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Status\":\"ON\"}]",
        "subMenu": [
            {},
            {}
        ]
    }
]
```

and the response that i want is like this:

```
    [{
    "tmus_Username": "epirsch",
    "tmap_App_ID": "COSY",
    "tmar_Role_ID": "C1",
    "tmar_Role_Desc": "ORDERS INFO",
    "tmar_Role_Ref": "OrdersInfo",
    "tmar_Role_Icon": "",
    "subMenuText": "",
    "subMenu": null
}, {
    "tmus_Username": "epirsch",
    "tmap_App_ID": "COSY",
    "tmar_Role_ID": "C2",
    "tmar_Role_Desc": "TRANSPORT",
    "tmar_Role_Ref": "",
    "tmar_Role_Icon": "",
    "subMenuText": "[{\"TMRP_Privilege_ID\":\"P10\",\"TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID\":\"C2\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Desc\":\"Transport Creating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Ref\":\"TransportCreate\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Status\":\"ON\"},{\"TMRP_Privilege_ID\":\"P11\",\"TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID\":\"C2\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Desc\":\"Transport Updating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Ref\":\"TransportUpdating\",\"TMRP_Privilege_Status\":\"ON\"}]",
    "subMenu": [{
        "TMRP_Privilege_ID": "P10",
        "TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID": "C2",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Desc": "Transport Creating",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Ref": "TransportCreate",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Status": "ON"
    }, {
        "TMRP_Privilege_ID": "P11",
        "TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID": "C2",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Desc": "Transport Updating",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Ref": "TransportUpdating",
        "TMRP_Privilege_Status": "ON"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Instead of a long list of using,  post the class MenuResponse and a json  you want to see

Comment: ready, i changed the classes and i put the List that i want

Comment: Thank you. It looks good. I only didn't ask you to delete the json you have now and the code that created it. Pls return it. I only told you we don't need a long list of namespaces.

Comment: Try auto-generating your class using one of the tools from [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Comment: @Serge . I am sorry, i put all classes and the example of the wrong json and the whised json

Comment: `(the submenu lists are empty objects but the number of registers are correct` Means the count of submenu is right but you can't get any value in List<SubMenu>?

Comment: yes, the count is correct but the objects are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to fix your SubMenu class by adding {get;set;}

```
public class SubMenu
{
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_ID { get; set; }
        public string? TMRP_TMAR_Role_ID { get; set; }
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Desc { get; set; }
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Ref { get; set; }
        public string? TMRP_Privilege_Status { get; set; }
}
```

and IMHO you don't need try..catch here, use this code

```
     var subMenuText = reader.GetString(6);
     menuResponse.subMenuText = subMenuText; // do you really need it?
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subMenuText))
       menuResponse.subMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubMenu>>(subMenuText);
```

Comment: thank you @Serge. i forget made correctly the SubMenu Pojo. in this case i use subMenu Text like check point to see the submenu data (i will remove it)