# C# JObject.Parse treats numbers as int64 instead of uint64

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, biginteger

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(str);
```

If the given json str has the attribute

```
"seed":11405418255883340000
```

Error will be thrown: `JsonReaderException: JSON integer 11405418255883340000 is too large or small for an Int64`

As you'll notice, 11405418255883340000 is too big for int64. But is a legitimate uint64.

Is this a bug or expected? What's the easiest workaround?

Comment: Is that Newtonsoft? Either way it seems it uses int64 to represent numbers, not uint64. Regardless of what is legitimate, you won't be able to change that. The easiest solution is to pass smaller numbers. If you can't do this then you have to use a different parser.

Comment: I tested var str =@"{""seed"":11405418255883340000 }";
 var jobject = JObject.Parse(str); NO any errors.

Comment: This is using Unity c# .NET 4.0 and of course the json is the response from an external website so I need some way to handle it gracefully. I've coded a gimmicky removal of the seed before parsing it with the json parser.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to create a DTO that matches the payload you expect and then set the type to `ulong` of the seed property.

Here is an example DTO:

```
public class Seeder {
  public ulong Seed {get;set;}
}
```

And here is how you use it, instead of Parse:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = @"{""seed"":11405418255883340000}";
    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
    var jr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str));
    var seed = ser.Deserialize<Seeder>(jr);
    seed.Dump();
}
```

This is what LinqPad shows me:

[image]

If I change the property type back to `long` I get this exception:

> Error converting value 11405418255883340000 to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'seed', line 1, position 28.

Note that you don't have to code a fully specified DTO object. This one works as wel, where we simply don't have the seed property on our DTO class:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = @"{""seed"":11405418255883340000, ""bar"": 4}";
    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
    var jr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str));
    var seed = ser.Deserialize<Seeder>(jr);
    seed.Dump();
}

public class Seeder {
  public int Bar {get;set;}
}
```

If you are lazy you can drop the JSON payload into an online class generator and/or tooling in your IDE. See for a starting point on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21611680

Answer (score 1):

**You need `System.Numerics` so that it can handle `BigInteger`.** The default is to use `long` not `ulong`, so it will get an overflow. Then it will try to parse it as a `BigInteger`.

The comments in [the JSON.Net source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/0a2e291c0d9c0c7675d445703e51750363a549ef/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L2246) say

```cs
#if HAVE_BIG_INTEGER
        // By using the BigInteger type in a separate method,
        // the runtime can execute the ParseNumber even if 
        // the System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse method is
        // missing, which happens in some versions of Mono
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static object BigIntegerParse(string number, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(number, culture);
        }
#endif
```

So if you can add that library to your project then it should work.

But your best bet is to just use a proper object model, like the other answer says.