# How Can I Deserialize and Get the values from the ReportData Node in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, deserialization

I have to parse an deserialize all the values from the following JSON file:

But I'm getting errors from the compiler.

```json
[
    {
        "CompanyInfo": {  
            "Company": "AdventureWorks",
            "Id": "AW01"
        },
        "ReportsToGenerate": 
        [
            {
                "Type_Report": "Type A Report",
                "Report_Title": "Human Resources Report",
                "Report_Data": 
                [               
                   {
                      "BusinessEntityID":168,
                      "FirstName":"Garrett",
                      "MiddleName":"R",                   
                      "Rate":9.5000
                   },
                   {
                      "BusinessEntityID":278,
                      "FirstName":"Garrett",
                      "MiddleName":"R",
                      "Rate":23.0769
                   }
                ]   
            },
            {
                "Type_Report": "Type B Report",
                "Report_Title": "Sales Report",
                "Report_Data": 
                [
                       {
                          "BusinessEntityID":282,
                          "FirstName":"José",
                          "MiddleName":"Edvaldo",                         
                          "DueDate":"2011-06-12T00:00:00"
                       },
                       {
                          "BusinessEntityID":282,
                          "FirstName":"José",
                          "MiddleName":"Edvaldo",                         
                          "DueDate":"2011-06-12T00:00:00"
                       }
                ]
            },          
        ]
    }
]
```

I've been trying with this code, But I cannot access the `Report_Data` node values:

```
public class Report
    {
        public string Type_Report {  get; set; }
        public string Report_Title {  get; set; }
        public List<Report_Data> Report_Data { get; set; }       
    }
```

```
public class Report
    {
        public string Type_Report {  get; set; }
        public string Report_Title {  get; set; }
        public List<Report_Data> Report_Data { get; set; }       
    }
```

```
public class Report_Data
    {
        public List<TypeAStructure> ReportData_TypeAStructure { get; set; }
        public List<TypeBStructure> ReportData_TypeBStructure { get; set; }
        public List<TypeCStructure> ReportData_TypeCStructure { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class TypeAStructure
    {        
        public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationLevel { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        public int SickLeaveHours { get; set; }
        public string HireDate { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string ShiftName { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

```
try
{
    jsonContent = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    List<Root> root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonContent);
    string sequenceValue = new string(nameFile.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

    foreach (var rootItem in root)
    {
        var companyName = rootItem.CompanyInfo.Company;
        var companyId = rootItem.CompanyInfo.Id;

        foreach (var report in rootItem.ReportsToGenerate)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(   "hey");
            
            foreach (var listA in report.Report_Data)
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(   "Hey2");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (System.Text.Json.JsonException ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, $"There was a deserialization issue with {nameFile}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, $"There was a general exception issue with {nameFile}");
}
```

I was trying with different llops and structures but I cannot access to the information, I am receiving a System Null Reference Exception and I cannot continue with my application.

Each time that I need to access to the content I receive the same error and I really need to get the values from this Node according with the type of report.

I am working With Newtonsoft Library in my Solution.

How can I deserialize and get the values from the ReportData Node in C#, without changing the source file structure?

Comment: What does your `Root` type look like?  Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that we can compile, run and debug?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? Which value is null?

Comment: According to your JSON example, Report_Data and the TypeAStructure, etc., should be flattened. I understand that you are trying to deserialize in a polymorphic manner, but that is a secondary concern. First eliminate the ReportData_ lists, since that doesn't match the JSON.

Comment: Try generating your classes using one of the tools from [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below working code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ReportData
{
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public string DueDate { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public string Type_Report { get; set; }
    public string Report_Title { get; set; }
    public List<ReportData> Report_Data { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyInfo
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public CompanyInfo CompanyInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Report> ReportsToGenerate { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            {
                ""CompanyInfo"": {
                    ""Company"": ""AdventureWorks"",
                    ""Id"": ""AW01""
                },
                ""ReportsToGenerate"": [
                    {
                        ""Type_Report"": ""Type A Report"",
                        ""Report_Title"": ""Human Resources Report"",
                        ""Report_Data"": [
                            {
                                ""BusinessEntityID"": 168,
                                ""FirstName"": ""Garrett"",
                                ""MiddleName"": ""R"",
                                ""Rate"": 9.5000
                            },
                            {
                                ""BusinessEntityID"": 278,
                                ""FirstName"": ""Garrett"",
                                ""MiddleName"": ""R"",
                                ""Rate"": 23.0769
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        ""Type_Report"": ""Type B Report"",
                        ""Report_Title"": ""Sales Report"",
                        ""Report_Data"": [
                            {
                                ""BusinessEntityID"": 282,
                                ""FirstName"": ""José"",
                                ""MiddleName"": ""Edvaldo"",
                                ""DueDate"": ""2011-06-12T00:00:00""
                            },
                            {
                                ""BusinessEntityID"": 282,
                                ""FirstName"": ""José"",
                                ""MiddleName"": ""Edvaldo"",
                                ""DueDate"": ""2011-06-12T00:00:00""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]";

        List<RootObject> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

        foreach (var rootObject in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Company:"+rootObject.CompanyInfo.Company, "Id" +rootObject.CompanyInfo.Id);

            foreach (var report in rootObject.ReportsToGenerate)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type Report:" +report.Type_Report+"Report Title:"+report.Report_Title);

                foreach (var reportData in report.Report_Data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BusinessEntityID: "+reportData.BusinessEntityID+ "FirstName:"+reportData.FirstName, "MiddleName:"+reportData.MiddleName +"Rate: " +reportData.Rate+" DueDate: "+reportData.DueDate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> working code .NETFiddle  [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZImqT)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% percent sure what you are needed to do in your code, but I have needed to do something similar myself. I will share the code I use to parse a List of JSON objects I get from a queue. Hopefully this helps.

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to do this.

Here a sample JSON object:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "MessageType": 1,
  "Answers": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Id": 0,
      "Answer": "2",
      "QuestionId": 1,
      "SectionId": 1
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "Id": 0,
      "Answer": "2",
      "QuestionId": 2,
      "SectionId": 1,
    }    
  ],
  "Totals": [
    {
      "$id": "22",
      "Id": 0,
      "SectionId": 1,
      "Total": 9
    },
    {
      "$id": "23",
      "Id": 0,
      "SectionId": 2,
      "Total": 17
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code that parses each object:

```
foreach (var message in evnt.Records)
{
    var stringMessageBody = message.Body;
    JObject jsonMessageBody = JObject.Parse(stringMessageBody);

    try
    {
        var print = ((JArray)jsonMessageBody["Answers"]).ToString();
        if (print != "[]")
        {
            var messageType = (JValue)jsonMessageBody["MessageType"];
            type = (string)messageType;

            switch ((int)messageType)
            {
                case (int)MessageType.Standard:
                    // Pull the Answers out of the new JObject
                    var answers = (JArray)jsonMessageBody["Answers"];

                    // Send the answers to be processed
                    await ProcessAnswersAsync(answers);
                    break;
                case (int)MessageType.Cat1:
                    // Pull the Answers out of the new JObject
                    var cat1Answers = (JArray)jsonMessageBody["Answers"];
                    var totals = (JArray)jsonMessageBody["Totals"];

                    // Send the answers to be processed
                    await ProcessCat1AnswersAsync(cat1Answers, totals);
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Message {counter} has been processed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message {counter} was empty, processing next message...");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error handling
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"There are {totalMessages - counter} messages left to process...");
    counter ++;
}
Console.WriteLine("All records have been processed.");
```