# C# handling multiple elements in a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
    "name": "ML4 093 Historical",
    "unit": "pounds",
    "data":[
        {
            "date": "1985-12-01",
            "value": "250"
        },
        {
            "date": "1985-11-01",
            "value": "237"
        },
        {
            "date": "1985-10-01",
            "value": "286"
        }
    ]
}
```

Long story short, I need to get the value that corresponds to a specific date (for example, 250 for 1985-12-01 or 237 for 1985-11-01).

I understand how to get the information for a single element (for example, getting pounds for unit), but I have no clue how to go about doing it in this case.

This is what I have to get the information for a single element:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Label unitname = label3;

            string QUERY_URL = "JSON URL HERE";
                Uri queryUri = new Uri(QUERY_URL);

            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                  var json_data = client.DownloadString(queryUri);

                  var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json_data);

                  var rootElement = jsonDocument.RootElement;

                  var unitElement = rootElement.GetProperty("unit");

                  var unit = unitElement.GetString();

                  unitname.Text = unit;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

JSON URL HERE is, obviously, replaced with the actual URL in the code - I just can't share it publicly.

Comment: Go over to https://json2csharp.com/ (no affiliation), paste in your JSON from above, press Convert to have it infer the C# class declarations and code needed to read/extract it.

Comment: Incidentally, `JsonDocument` is disposable, so you need to do `using var jsonDocument = ...`

Comment: You could also do Paste JSON As Classes in Visual Studio to get a model to deserialize to. See [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class representing this JSON object (keeping in mind that Data should be an entirely separate object, inside the parent object), like so:

```
    public class DataObject
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Then to retrieve the value, an example would be:

```
var rootElement = (DataObject)jsonDocument.RootElement;  //there are other better ways to do this - you might want to take a look at Automapper library
var unitElement = rootElement.Data[1].Value  //to get the first data value element.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model class

DataModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyFoodBag.Forecast.Presentation.Forecaster.Models
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that just a little modification in you code should work

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Label unitname = label3;

            string QUERY_URL = "JSON URL HERE";
            Uri queryUri = new Uri(QUERY_URL);

            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                  var json_data = client.DownloadString(queryUri);
                  // map json to model object
                  var dataModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(json_data);

                  var valueForDate = dataModel.Data.Where(x => x.Date == <whateverdate>).Select(v => v.Value);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with Following

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
 {
     conn.Open();
    //unit and name
    //data colletion with bellow code
    foreach (<listname> objName in requestObj.CollectionName)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        
        using (adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    
            PropertyInfo[] props = requestObj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
       
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ParameterName", CollectionName.object));
    
            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
}
```