# Deserialize json with dynamic objects that starts with pattern

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some json that looks like this

```json
{
   "id":"2021",
   "descriptions_bg":[
      "30231300",
      "30233160",
      "32420000",
      "30214000"
   ],
   "descriptions_cs":[
      "30231300",
      "30233160",
      "32420000",
      "30214000"
   ],
   "descriptions_da":[
      "30231300",
      "30233160",
      "32420000",
      "30214000"
   ],
   "official_title_bg":"П",
   "official_title_cs":"P",
   "official_title_da":"P",
   "auth_town_bg":"AuthTown",
   "auth_town_cs":"AuthTown",
   "auth_town_da":"AuthTown"
}
```

The problem here being, that there can come an infinite number of items in both `descriptions_*`, `official_title_*` and `auth_town_*` with different endings.

I've tried to make classes and members like `public string official_title_* { get; set; }`in C# to deserialize to with Newtonsoft Json, but that (of course) doesn't work.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic?
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: Does this answer help? [c# parsing relaxed json to make a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45837283/880990).

Comment: @Gleb Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies, it's almost always a terrible idea to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to deserialize to `Dictionary<string, JToken>` and based on `Key` and `Object Type` you can write business logic. With the combination of `Linq` you can filter the `Key`

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>(json);

foreach(var item in dict.Where(x=>x.Key.StartsWith("descriptions_")))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} is type {item.Value.GetType()}");
}

foreach (var item in dict.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("auth_town_")))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} is type {item.Value.GetType()}");
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use `JToken` instead of `object`, but this will work.

Comment: @DavidG make sense, I have updated the post with JToken

Comment: Thanks. So every key, also the known ones (for example id) needs to be handled this way?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method, using a class object that defines each group of properties that have a common prefix as a `Dictionary<string, TValue>`.

The JSON is deserialized using a custom JsonConverter that maps each group of properties in the JSON to a Property of the class, using a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    ["Descriptions"] = "descriptions_",
    ["OfficialTitles"] = "official_title_",
    ["AuthTowns"] = "auth_town_"
};
```

All properties in the JSON that map to a Property in the class are added to the corresponding Dictionary and the values converted to the Type defined by the class property.

Note: you need to adapt the mapper and class Properties to the JSON. You could make the procedure more *generic* using some logic to determine when Property Name in the JSON belongs to the same *group* and generate a new `Dictionary<string, TValue>` to add to the class by reflection.
Or simply add more Properties to the class *off-line*, if you find other groups.

Call it as:
(possibly giving the class a less silly name :)

```
var result = new SimpleSequences().Deserialize(json);
```

Helper class object:

```
private class SimpleSequences
{
    public SimpleSequences() {
        Descriptions = new Dictionary<string, long[]>();
        OfficialTitles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        AuthTowns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public List<SimpleSequences> Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            Converters = new[] { new SimpleSequencesConverter() }
        };
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SimpleSequences>>(json, options);
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, long[]> Descriptions { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> OfficialTitles { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> AuthTowns { get; set; }
}
```

Custom JsonConverter:

This converter handles a single object or array of objects (as shown in your question), but always return a `List<SimpleSequences>` (which may contain a single object). Modify as required.

```
public class SimpleSequencesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject) {
            throw new Exception($"Unexpected Type. Expecting Array or Object, got {reader.TokenType}");
        }
        var elementsList = new List<SimpleSequences>();

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
            elementsList.Add(GetPropertyValues(JObject.Load(reader)));
        }
        else {
            while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray) {
                elementsList.Add(GetPropertyValues(JObject.Load(reader)));
            }
        }
        return elementsList;
    }

    private SimpleSequences GetPropertyValues(JToken token)
    {
        var element = new SimpleSequences();
        element.Id = token["id"].ToObject<int>();
        var descriptions = token.Children().Where(t => t.Path.StartsWith(map["Descriptions"]));

        foreach (JProperty p in descriptions) {
            element.Descriptions.Add(p.Path, p.Value.ToObject<long[]>());
        }

        var titles = token.Children().Where(t => t.Path.StartsWith(map["OfficialTitles"]));
        foreach (JProperty p in titles) {
            element.OfficialTitles.Add(p.Path, p.Value.ToString());
        }

        var authTowns = token.OfType<JToken>().Where(t => t.Path.StartsWith(map["AuthTowns"]));
        foreach (JProperty p in authTowns) {
            element.AuthTowns.Add(p.Path, p.Value.ToString());
        }
        return element;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        ["Descriptions"] = "descriptions_",
        ["OfficialTitles"] = "official_title_",
        ["AuthTowns"] = "auth_town_"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution could be to use several [LINQ2JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) queries.

For instance, if you want to get all `description_xyz` collections in a single list
then you can do that like this:

```
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);

var descriptionProperties = semiParsedJson.Properties()
    .Where(prop => prop.Name.StartsWith("descriptions_"));

var collectionOfDescriptions =
    from desc in descriptionProperties.Values()
    select ((JArray)desc).ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>();

var flattenedDescriptions = collectionOfDescriptions.
    SelectMany(desc => desc)
    .ToList();
```

- We can semi parse the json by using `JObject.Parse`
- We can perform some filtering based on the properties' `Name` field
- We can then get all values form each `description_xyz` collections as `IEnumerable<string>`
- We will have at this point a collection of collections `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, which we can flatten with `SelectMany`
- At very end we can materialize the query with `ToList`