# Array of array returning NaN

Tags: javascript

So why myarray[bla][bl] always equal to NaN? If I do the same thing with 1 dimension (myarray[bla]), I get the number.

```
var bla = 'blabla';
var bl = 'bla';
var myarray = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!myarray[bla]) {
        myarray[bla] = [];
    }
    myarray[bla][bl] += i;
    console.log(myarray[bla][bl] + " + " + i);
}​
```

Comment: because myarray[bla][bl] is not set...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so let's step through your loop, replacing instances of the variable `bla` with the string value of `'blabla'`:

```
if (!myarray['blabla']) {
  myarray['blabla'] = [];
}
```

Arrays in javascript are index by integer values.  What your code here is doing is adding an expando property to the array instance named `blabla`.  That is:

```
myarray.blabla = [];
```

now reconsider your increment statement:

```
myarray['blabla'][bl] += i;
```

or, with the expando properties:

```
myarray.blabla.bl  // remember that "myarray.blabla" is set to the empty array above
```

What this is trying to do is access the property named `bl` on the empty array.  That's why you're getting `undefined` here.

Anyway, as a best practice, you might want to avoid using arrays in javascript like hashtables, since problems like this are bound to crop up after enough time.

Comment: Best practice for hashtables in javascript would be JSON I guess? I come from a perl background where hashes are all you need to know.

Comment: @David - Kind of - there's actually a difference between JSON objects and javascript objects, as detailed here better than I ever could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/ - but in general, yeah, you can sometimes use simple object instances as hashtables.  One notable exception where this *won't* work is where your hashtable key type is something other than a simple string - like a custom object type.  This page has some nice explanations of why objects/arrays act the way they do: http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/

Answer (score 0):

If we expand a little I hope you can see the problem,

```
if (!myarray[bla]) {
    myarray[bla] = [];
}
myarray[bla][bl] = myarray[bla][bl] + i;
```

Hint: `myarray[bla][bl] = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

because `myarray[bla][bl]` is not set... , you need

```
if ( !myarray[bla][bl] ){ myarray[bla][bl] = 0; }
```