# Perform a `typeof JSON` comparison

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I have a method that receives something and it needs to determine the type of the received value. I can use the `typeof` thing to perform regular comparisons like if it is a number or a string. But how can I do this for JSON objects? Comparing them with `JSON` brings up the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got  #< Object>

So I guess that comparing a JSON object type with `JSON` is not the way?

The original code is like:

```
check = (what) ->
  if what instanceof JSON
    alert "Yooo"

check({compare: "me"})
```

Comment: Anyway the question doesn't make sense; JSON is either a string or an object; there's no JSON "type" in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy yes, excuse me, it was `instanceof` :) fixed that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object unless you mean the native  `window.JSON` object which hosts 2 methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type will be `object`, not `JSON`. To see what you're working with, you can check if it has the properties you're looking for. Check the length, or if it has specific keys.

Here's a pretty good informational page on working with JSON. [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: So I was thinking totally wrong. I am coming from the strictly typed languages land, so this is expected :)

Comment: FYI - the "JSON in JavaScript" link returned a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

First `type of` return string, second, there is no such thing as Type `JSON` in `type of` possible return values. [see the this page for detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

in your case you will receive `"object"`.

Answer (score 1):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object notation and is simply a name for how object literals are written in JavaScript it is not a type.

```
var a = {"foo":"My foo","bar" : 4};
var b = {"foo":"My foo","bar" : 0};
var c = {"foo":"My c foo","barella" : -1};
var d = '{"baz":"My baz","bar" : 4}';
```

a,b,c and d are all objects the first three of type object the fourth of type string. You could from a type theoretic point of view say that the first two have the same type. If you did `eval("var e =" + d)` then the string would be in d would be evaluated and since d is an object serialized to JSON the result would be a valid object that would be assigned to e.

in other words JSON is no type it's part of the JavaScript grammar, the result of evaluating JSON is an object and the type of that object will vary depending on the object literal. using `typeof` on such an object will yield "object" (regards less of the type theoretic type of the object).

If you wish to test and object against a specific type you would therefor have to test it for all the expected properties and methods

Comment: In your example a, b, and c are all objects and d is a string, **but _none_ are JSON**. d is _almost_ JSON except that it doesn't have double-quoted property names which are required by [JSON](http://json.org) grammar. JSON is _not_ part of JavaScript grammar. The result of _parsing_ JSON is an object. The term "JSON" applies only to string representations of objects as defined at [json.org](http://json.org). Note also that not all JavaScript objects can be represented as JSON (because JSON doesn't have an `undefined` type and doesn't do functions).

Comment: @nnnnnn JavaScript object notation === JSON. Quotes are optional and all object literals in JavaScript are written using JavaScript object notation. The Hole point is that JSON is valid JavaScript and my point with the objects above are to show why JavaScript object notation is not a type

Comment: Yes, "JSON" is an acronymn for JavaScript Object Notation, but JSON is a _string_ format for _data interchange_ and its grammar is a subset of what is valid in JavaScript. (This means JSON can be used with just about any modern programming language - that's the point.) JS object literals in JS code are _not_ JSON. Quotes are optional in JS object literals but not in JSON - missing quotes doesn't matter if you're going to use `eval` on your JSON, but that's bad practice. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object).

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm with you on the quotes part (which was new to me since all the parsers I've worked with really don't care) the rest however is not accurate according to rfc4627. What you define as JSON is a JSON **text** and not the format it self. And to be precise it's a subset of (derived from) the ECMAScript grammar. And all this is still irrelevant to the answer and question since the examples are about JSON not being a type but a format

Comment: When the actual acronym "JSON" is used it refers to the data interchange format that was based on JS object literal syntax, _not_ to actual JS code. These are two distinct concepts. If you read rfc4627 it says that "JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a text format for the serialization of structured data. It is derived from the object literals of JavaScript" - that is, it backs up what I'm saying not what you're saying. Note that http://json.org presents the same info as rfc4627 in a more readable format.

Comment: @nnnnnn to be even more precise d is **not** JSON because the definition **requires** the first character to be {. JSON is often represented with string literals but those are platform dependant and might or might not require quotes or other leading characters.

Comment: Fair enough about other platforms, but in this case the first character is a { because it is the content of the string that matters, not how it is created. Note that valid JSON can start with a square bracket [.

Answer (score 1):

```
class JSON
   constructor: (@data) ->

   get: (key) ->
     @data[key]

   set: (key, value) ->
     @data[key] = value

a = new JSON "foo":"My foo", "bar" : 4

a.get('foo')
a.data.foo
a.data['foo']

console.log(a instanceof JSON)
```

:D You really shouldn't be doing this though, at least not to create a JSON type. But it's possible that you can create your own wrapper for pretty much anything. Combining this with the Object.defineProperty to setup getters and setters based on @data, you could do some powerful stuff. It doesn't have method_missing methods, but you can achieve similar results with Object.defineProperty