# JavaScript Object/Array to JSON Conversion

Tags: json, parsing

I need a simple code example showing javascript object and converting it to JSON....
I have done conversion based on javascript Array to JSON using $.ParseJSON(array mentioned here)....Now i need reverse of it...In the end I need to send it to the server using post method...Kindly Guide.

This code i got on internet...

```
var jsonArg1 = new Object();
    jsonArg1.name = 'calc this';
    jsonArg1.value = 3.1415;
var jsonArg2 = new Object();
    jsonArg2.name = 'calc this again';
    jsonArg2.value = 2.73;

var pluginArrayArg = new Array();
    pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg1);
    pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg2);

to convert pluginArrayArg (which is pure javascript array) into JSON array:

var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pluginArrayArg))
```

Here is one of the code that I saw on internet...but it seems as if in the start they are declaring JSON and not the assocaite array elements...Kindly guide me the proper way.Thanks

Comment: I think you have to first get the terminology straight. [There is no such thing as a "JSON object" or "array"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). There are only JavaScript objects/arrays and JSON. You can parse a *string* containing JSON to a JS object/array using `JSON.parse`. You can convert a JS object/array to a string using `JSON.stringify`. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, at the start they are not declaring JSONS its called javascript object..Javascript object is different from Json.To find the difference between the both check [What's the difference between Javascript Object and JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object)

To convert javscript object or array to json, use `JSON.stringify(varname)` . Also, to print objects in javascript use `console.log(objname)`.
Add this to your code,

```
var jsonArg1 = new Object();
jsonArg1.name = 'calc this';
jsonArg1.value = 3.1415;
var jsonArg2 = new Object();
jsonArg2.name = 'calc this again';
jsonArg2.value = 2.73;
var pluginArrayArg = new Array();
pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg1);
pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg2);
console.log(pluginArrayArg);
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(pluginArrayArg);
alert(jsonArray);
```

Also, to convert an associative array in javascript to JSON, try this example..

```
var asscArr = {};
asscArr["name"] = "Hello World";
console.log("name = " + asscArr["name"]);
var jsonArr = JSON.stringify(asscArr);
alert(jsonArr);
```