# Why do complex types work on a reference value

Tags: javascript, complextype

This is one of those niggling little questions that hasn't caused me any issues *yet* (which is increasingly surprising the more that I think about it) but bothers me any ways and I can't seem to find a sufficient answer anywhere else.

Suppose I have two examples

**Example 1**

```
var foo = [1,2],
    bar = foo;

bar[0] = 9;
console.log(foo, bar);
```

This will output [9,2] [9,2].

**Example 2**

```
var foo = [1,2],
    bar = [1,2];

bar[0] = 9;
console.log(foo, bar);
```

This will output [1,2] [9,2].

From a technical standpoint what's the difference between **Example 1** and **Example 2**?

In example one it looks like you are initializing bar as the value of foo but only changing the value of bar. Why does bar[0] = 9 in **Example 1** also change the value stored in foo?

On the flip side what if I wanted to do exactly that. Say I had no way of knowing what the value of foo was at run time but wanted to initialize bar at the same value as foo and then later change the value of bar and only bar how would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18359093/1316573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Example 1 there is no value copying taking place, but you assign the reference of `foo` to variable `bar`.

Now they both point to the same object (array, at the same memory location), hence when you change the array item in one of them it changes the same memory location that both variables are **pointing** to.

To answer the question at the bottom, you would need to make a copy/clone of `foo` at then assign that clone (which will be a new object instance) to `bar`. Then you are in the situation in Example 2, where you can change them independently.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
bar = foo;
```

is equivalent to saying "bar points to the same thing as foo"

Whereas assigning them both to [1,2], they both point to different elements, so you can modify one without chaing the other.

If you want to modify bar without changing foo, you should use:

```
var foo = [1,2];
var bar = foo.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

An array in Javascript is a reference type.

In example one, you have one array with two variables pointing to it.
If you access either one of two variables, you will update the underlying array. When you log it, it's the same array you're logging.

In example two, there are two arrays, each with a variable pointing to it. When you access a variable, it will access the corresponding Array.

If you want to initialize a new array based on a previous one without referencing the same array, you need to copy the variables:

```
var foo = [1, 2],
    bar = [];

for (var i = 0; i<foo.length;i++){
    bar.push(foo[i]);
}

// or a shortcut:
bar = foo.slice(0);
```

This goes for Arrays, but also for any object in JS. With objects this is referred to as `cloning` (or `deep-cloning` if you also want to copy all child objects.