# how to define attributes for all properties of an object simultaneously (or set default)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, properties, defineproperty

I'm writing an AngularJS service provider (function) that:

- takes results from a number of different tables of an SQLite database
- returns the object to various controller functions

The service queries different tables (which have different columns) so the `result` object has different properties - depending on which table the data was sourced from.

- it's therefore not possible to use `Object.defineProperties` for specific object properties since i don't know the properties prior to the query 'case' being created
- i suppose I could define the object variable properties within the 'switch' but that seems messy...

When the object is returned to the controller functions there is some manipulation required

- i need to be able to overwrite some properties in the returned object (ie need `writable: true`)
- to be precise, JSON.parse() then overwrite of various properties since arrays stored in the SQLite DB are converted with JSON.stringify() prior to INSERT then stored as strings in the DB
- i'm running into trouble since the default for the object is `writable: false`

Question:
**How do i define an object to have attributes `configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: true` for all (future) properties of an object ?**  ie how to set the *default* attributes for an object since I don't (yet) know the exact property names of the object ?

Sample code:

```
this.checkRowExists = function(table, id) {     
    try {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        switch (table) {
            case "table1" :
                var selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE id=?';
                break;
            case "table2" :
                var selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE id=?';
                break;
            case "table3" :
                var selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE id=?';
                break;
        }

        this.db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(selectQuery, [id], function(tx, results) {
                    if (results.rows.length > 0){
                        var myRow = {};       // <- how to define all properties in "myRow" object as configurable and writable ??
                        var myRow = results.rows.item(0);
                        deferred.resolve(myRow);  // <- object "myRow" is returned here to various controller functions
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve(results.rows.length);
                    }
            }, function(tx, error) {
                    console.log('checkRowExists: Error occurred while searching for profile.', error);
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    } catch(exception) {
        console.log('checkRowExists: Error occurred while trying this function.', exception);
    }
};
```

PS the code works fine, but just returns an object with `writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false` while i need everything to be `true`

EDIT:
Questions remaining even after partial solution below:
- why can't a property descriptor be changed manually using the `Object.defineProperty` method ?
- why is `enumerable: true` when the default should be false ?  is this related to SQlite db transactions?
- why are the defaults of `writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false` not being applied to the new object being cloned using the JSON method?
**Answer** is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Example:_Adding_properties_and_default_values) - depends on how the object is created - see comment below

Comment: That's impossible, but I don't even see where your code is setting the `writable` attribute to `false`?

Comment: according to this the writable attribute / property descriptor is set to FALSE by default https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: No, only if you have a property descriptor and omit one attribute, then that one will default to `false` when the property descriptor object is used to create a property. But in properties that already exist nothing is changed, and in properties that are created by simple assignments all attributes default to `true`.

Comment: yes partially true - was wondering how the 'default = false' but on new objects it mostly appears to be "true" - the answer is that it depends on how the object property is defined - so if an object is defined like `myObject={}; myObject.a=1;` all default to true, but defined like `Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'a', { value: 1 });` any undefined descriptors default to false.  Rather confusing. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Example:_Adding_properties_and_default_values

Comment: Yes, that's just what I said :-)

Answer (score 0):

half the problem seems to be that the object `myRow` inherits the property descriptors / attributes of the object that it is copied from ie:
`var myRow = results.rows.item(0)`

the other half of the problem is that it doesn't seem possible to change the property descriptors:
ie using `Object.defineProperty(myRow, "my_property", {configurable: true});`
-> gives `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: my_property`

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**
according to the 3rd answer in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/728694#728694) the most elegant way to clone an object is to use:
`var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject));`
which seems to create an entirely new object, that doesn't inherit property descriptors from the 'copied' object

for whatever reason this results in an object with
`writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true`  (tested in Chrome & Safari)
(and yes that doesn't make sense given the defaults of `false` for all 3 descriptors listed in the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty))
**EDIT:**
this is because of the way the object is defined - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Example:_Adding_properties_and_default_values)
- defined like `myObject={}; myObject.a=1;` all property descriptors default to true,
- defined like `Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'a', { value: 1 });` any undefined descriptors default to false

so the output of the following snippet from the code above looks like:

```
tx.executeSql(selectQuery, [id], function(tx, results) {
    if (results.rows.length > 0){
            // see what the original object descriptors are set at:
            console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(results.rows.item(0), "my_property") );
            // -> outputs "configurable: false, enumerable: true, writable: false"
        var myRow = results.rows.item(0);
            // see what the new copied object descriptors are set at:
            console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myRow, "my_property") );
            // -> outputs "configurable: false, enumerable: true, writable: false"
        var myRow2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results.rows.item(0)));
            // see what the new JSON cloned object descriptors are set at:
            console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myRow, "my_property") );
            // -> outputs "configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true"
        deferred.resolve(myRow2);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(results.rows.length);
    }
}, function(tx, error) {
        console.log('checkRowExists: Error occurred while searching for profile.', error);
    deferred.reject(error);
});
```

still have a couple of questions about this partial solution:
- what is the speed of using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));` to copy / clone an object ?
- are there other disadvantages of using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));` to clone ?
(some are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference) - mostly doesn't work with date formats or function within object properties)

Comment: to answer one of my questions, speed doesn't seem to be a concern with the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));` method - checked using `console.log(Date.now());` which results in `before 1419986858403` and `after 1419986858404` ie 1 millisecond for a 21 column db with a couple of nested arrays... ymmv.

Comment: If you still have multiple question, you should put those in your *question* post.

Comment: good call - moved any questions that weren't about the partial solution up to the _question_ post. thanks