# How access the whole array object into array.prototype

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write some like this :

```
Array.prototype.copy(obj_or_array) {
    if (obj_or_array instanceof Array)
    this.array = this.concat ( obj_or_array.slice());
    else    
    for(var key in obj_or_array) {this.push(obj_or_array[key]);}    
}
```

'this.array'  does not exist but I'd like to have it.
Any idea ? Is it impossible ?

Comment: Is this a typo? `obj instanceof Array` should be `obj_or_array instanceof Array`

Comment: Don't use this method to copy objects too as it's on the Array prototype.

Comment: What's the function actually supposed to do?

Comment: @Andy  ??? I dont understand you   >lolka_bolka: yes, edited & fixed

Comment: @Alnitak The purpose is to have an auto function to clone or copy array or object

Comment: Don't have attach a function to clone an object to the Array prototype. You should attach that to the Object prototype.

Comment: @Andy my thoughts exactly

Comment: Also, such a function should probably be a static method on `Object` rather than something that attempts to mutate the current `this` (the latter often being hard or even impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to clone an array using the method in your question:

```
if (!('copy' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.copy = function() {
    return this.slice(0);
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = arr.copy();
```

[And if your objects are always going to be simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18359187/1377002) (ie they don't have any methods), you could use something like this:

```
if (!('copy' in Object.prototype)) {
  Object.prototype.copy = function() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
  }
}

var obj = { name: 'andy' };
var obj2 = obj.copy();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uyxnnsqw/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
//Error checking and other stuff omitted this is only an EXAMPLE of an IDEA :)
Array.prototype.loadData = function (a)
{
    if(a instanceof Array)
      for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++) 
          this.push(a[i]);

    else if(a instanceof Object)
      for(var i in a) 
          this.push(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have. I'd like (but I think it is impossible to access to the array itself to play with map or concat... this.array = this.array.concat(a) (but 'this.array' does not exist)

Comment: Correct, `this.array` does not exist, `this` is the actual array, not `this.array`. How exactly do you want to "play" with that "map"? If you want to add/remove items you will still have to use push or other methods to change that array's state.

Comment: I'd like a way to make the job using only one line. From outside you can use Array = AnotherArray.slice() or Array1 =Array1,cancat(Array2( or Arra1 = Array2.map(a_Function...) . The problem is 'How to access to the 'arrayitself' inside the prototype'. The keyword 'this' can be used to use push, etc. But I can't find a way to access to the 'arrayitself' if it'd exis...