# Javascript - Referenced array deleting objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is. I'm expecting the req.query to be the same as it was set at the start but when I log them to the console at the end data and req.query only contain rnd.

```
var req = {};
req.query = {
    url: 'https://google.com/',
    width: '500',
    height: '190',
    ref: 'http://domain.tld',
    rnd: '9314871930982'
};
var data = req.query;
delete data.width;
delete data.height;
delete data.url;
delete data.ref;

console.log(req.query);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
var data = req.query;
```

you are making `data` refer the same object which `req.query` also refers.

```
+-----------------+                     +----------------------------+
|      data       |====================>| url:'https://google.com/'  |
+-----------------+                     | width: '500'               |
                                        | height: '190'              |
+-----------------+                     | ref: 'http://domain.tld'   |
|    req.query    |====================>| rnd: '9314871930982'       |
+-----------------+                     +----------------------------+
```

So, any change to the object, through either `data` or `req.query`, will be reflected on all the other references as well. Its more like accessing the same object with two different names.

With this understanding, if we look at your code, when you delete things from `data`, you are actually deleting from the object referred by `req.query`.

If you don't want this to happen, you need to clone `req.query` with any of the methods mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1903116).