# Why does changes in child object get reflected in parent object?

Tags: javascript

I am facing problems while creating another reference of a parent object list and making changes in it.eg

```
var cars = new Array();

var addCar = function(name,model) {
    this.name = name;
    this.model = model;
}

var car1 = new addCar("indica", "v2");
var car2 = new addCar("swift", "DLX");
var car1 = new addCar("innova", "HX");

cars.push(car1);
cars.push(car2);
cars.push(car3);
```

Now if we copy cars object in another object in fresh object and make changes in child object. The changes get reflected in the cars list array.

Comment: Because you're not actually copying them, you're just referencing them...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object