# Ecma6, Object.assign doesn't do a deep copy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
dst = { "a" : 1}
src = { "edf" : {"zyx" : "right"}}
Object.assign(dst, src)
src.edf.zyx = "wrong"
console.log(dst["edf"]["zyx"])
```

I expect to see `'right'` as the output but it prints `'wrong'`.

It means, `Object.assign` has not done a deep copy of complex objects from source to destination. How can i do deep copy?

Note: i am aware of `lodash.deepClone`, but i am trying to avoid outside frameworks

Comment: Yeah, `Object.assign()` only performs shallow merging of properties. But, there isn't currently a built-in function for deep merging, recursively discovering properties in nested objects.

Comment: you can use JSON, but that can be slow-ish for large data sets. still, it's as close to a built-in clone as possible and is actually faster than most library methods.

Comment: To note, parsing to and from JSON will not work for functions.

Comment: Own properties or prototypes too?

Comment: Sadly, it's not supposed to return a deep copy. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign

Comment: let dst = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src));  see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @JonathanLonowski what about `var newObj = eval(oldObj.toSource())` for es5 and `var newO={...old}` for es6?

Answer (score 0):

First I want to tell you that it's not bulletproof solution (in case of date object). If you want "right" as answer, here is your solution:

```
var dst,src = { "edf" : {"zyx" : "right"} };
dst = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src));
dst["a"] = 1;
src.edf.zyx = "wrong";
console.log(src, dst);
```

So please read these links to understand deep copy better

[Most elegant way to clone a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

[Copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference)

Comment: Try running this on my above example obj to see where it fails (specifically, date and function).

Comment: It will fail definitely that's why I have given the links & also mentioned 'If you want "right" as answer'.

Comment: Note that this does not copy over non-enumerable properties or symbols, so this is not bullet-proof.