# chai deep equal and equal not working

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Some how chai its not working

```
promise = doSomething()

expect(promise).to.eventually.equal(obj)

expect(promise).to.eventually.deep.equal(obj)
```

but in the assertion error I get this

`AssertionError: expected {a: "2", b: "3"} to equal {a: "2", b: "3"}`

BTW I already try with `should` and I get the same result

Comment: It's working for me with a simple `return expect(Promise.resolve({ a: "2", b: "3" })).to.eventually.deep.equal({ a: "2", b: "3" });`. Are you sure the result truly matches the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running both assertions? Using the `deep` flag is correct, since you shouldn't expect object equality.

Comment: No, Im not running both at the same time. @Jacob yes your solution works for me too using `when` but no thru my promise, the weird part is that the assertion error is getting the same values.

Comment: What plugins are you using? `chai-as-promised` is what I use.

Comment: I guess maybe the value return from promise is string of `JSON`, like `"{a: '2', b: '3'}"`, if so, try `JSON.parse()` this value before deep equal...

Comment: @Jacob yes Im using `chai-as-promised`

Comment: @zangw Didn't work I try converting both to strings aswell but is not working

Comment: @Charlires, any errors for your new test...

Comment: looking through their issue history, chai might be silently asserting against the string's prototype and other fields you don't normally see or consider on the string object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess maybe the value return from promise is string of JSON, like

`"{a: '2', b: '3'}"`

Which case I met before. If so, try `JSON.parse()` this value before deep equal operation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like chai checks more than the object structure.

I did this inside the promise `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))` and that make it work, so according to this question [How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference) I assume that chai is checking the reference of the objects, which makes no sense to me at all.

Not the solution I was expecting but works for me, is some one has a better solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` is a good way to look at what the object *actually* contains, in the case that they are both objects, look the same even in a console log but are not the same.

For example, chai `deep.equal` will recognize `{a:1, b:2}` and the similar object from a Mongoose instance as not the same but it wont actually tell you what is different ("+ expected - actual" being empty). `Object.getOwnPropertNames` will show the real contents of the object.