# Javascript: How can I preserve a variable from DOM changes

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

How can I preserve a set of (copies of) objects from the original DOM, so the set retains its original values despite DOM changes?

For example:

```
<body class="toc endnotes">
```

And runs a script including this:

```
function runFunxForBodyClasses()
{
    var bodyClass = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.trim();
    if( bodyClass ){
        // multiple body classes are space-delimited per html/css
        var bodyClasses = bodyClass.split(" ");
        if( bodyClasses.length > 0 ){

            var h2s = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
            var anchors = getAnchors();
            // debugging
            alert(anchors.length);

            // functions called below, affect the DOM and return void

            if( bodyClasses.indexOf('toc') > -1 ){
                addToc(h2s);
            }

            if( bodyClasses.indexOf('endnotes') > -1 ){
                addEndNotes(anchors);
            }

            // ... other irrelevant ones here
        }
    }
}

function getAnchors()
{
    return document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("a");
}

function addEndNotes(anchors)
{
    if( anchors.length < 1 ){
        return;
    }
    // debugging
    alert(anchors.length);
    // ...
```

With the variable `anchors`, I'm trying to preserve a list of anchor objects as it was when the page came from the server, and use that as input for `addEndNotes()`.

What `addEndNotes()` gets however is a list of anchor objects as modified by `addToc()`. `addToc()` adds links on h2's in a table of contents, say 'n' items. It does not use variable `anchors` nor anything of the same name.

Yet the second alert reports a number of items in `anchors` that is (original number + 2n): this list is being affected by changes in the DOM after `anchors` is declared and before it is used again.

Originally initialization of `anchors` was in global scope, but I learned from a page about variable scope that it's not really initialized until later if it's outside a function. So I put the anchor-getting in that function, but this made no difference in result.

Re another language I would say I'm wanting copies instead of references, how does one do this in JS?

Comment: What is in `addToc`

Comment: Can you provide a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by this chain of links:
  [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

[Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

[How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference)

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Apparently you need a "clone" function of some kind, Jquery's or other, to be sure of making a copy of an object that won't be affected by changes to the original (see the last link).