# Vue.js wrong variable gets updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a filter method (*itemsWithFilter*) to filter my *items* object and write the results in *itemsResult*

this works for the first time but it seems that my function autmatically updated the *items* object too. Even so I write the results in  *itemsResult* only.

Does anyone know why and how I can prevent it ? That *itemsWithFilter* methods returns the results to *itemsResult* only

**Here is the Fiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/afdz3yLt/1/

**Here is my itemsWithFilter function**

```
itemsWithFilter: function(filter) {

  var items = this.items.data;
  var result = {}


  console.log("Run itemsWithFilter")
  Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {

    const item = items[key]

    console.log(`filter: ${filter}: check item ${item.id} with category id: ${item.category.id}`)

    if (item.category.id == filter) {
      result[key] = item
    }
  })

  this.itemsResult.data = result

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that I am understanding the question wrong, but I think what you are meaning to ask is how to use `this.items.data` and write the result to `this.itemsResult.data` without `this.items.data` being updated as well. This is a typical JavaScript thing where a reference to an object always remains intact. What you are looking for (if my assumption about the question is correct) is to clone the `this.items.data` object. The best way to do that is 
`var items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items.data))`. More information in these questions:

[How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference)

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: you are a hero. it works if I parse the object.. don't understand the reference thing but will check your link. very strange tho.