# Why actual object updates with new values if I update reference variables In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Consider I have an object name `x` having value `x = { a: 'abc', b: 'jkl' }`,

Now I'm assigning this object `x` to new local variable `y` by `var y = x`.

when `var y` value **change with new value** `y.a = 'pqr', y.b = 'xyz'`, `var x` object auto updates with new value `{ a: 'pqr', b: 'xyz' }` of `var y`.

This is the good scenario but in some cases I want to prevent that. How can I achieve this?

You can find plunker code for this [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eWeQVzj8k8gYTJKS0jCQ?p=preview)

Comment: *"`var x` object auto updates with new value"* No it does not.

Comment: I don't think `var x` will auto update in this case, please share a snippet to replicate this!

Comment: Don't confuse `y = {a: 'pqr'}` and `y['a'] = 'pqr'`. Very different, these two.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Why, yes, it actually does, and there are very good duplicate targets against that behaviour. Sadly, Y'all have incorrectly closed it as unclear. If this gets reopened, here's a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference or https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/576767. There's a 2.5k+ upvotes question that explains that behaviour, how can you say it doesn't happen?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The question has been edited long after my comment. Look at the edit history for the original.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Good point. Let's just reopen then.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Why? You just pointed out that there are already two duplicates.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen so we can actually close them as duplicates. This is not an unclear question. Moreover, the original asks very much the same question, the revision added bold and a code sample, but the question was already there.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Might as well just vote to delete it. The original does *not* ask the same question. The original completely assigns a new object to `y` and then claims that this impacts `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to prevent that:

1 - `Object.assign`:

```js
var x = { a: 'abc', b: 'jkl' }
var y = Object.assign({}, x);
y.a = 'modified';
console.log('x: ', x);
console.log('y: ', y);
```

2 - `Spread operator`:

```js
var x = { a: 'abc', b: 'jkl' }
var y = { ...x };
y.a = 'modified';
console.log('x: ', x);
console.log('y: ', y);
```

Comment: That only takes care of one level. When you try this and then do `y.one.two` then you mutate x because `y.one` will still be a reference to `x.one`

Answer (score 1):

In the described scenario, `y` gets a new object and `x` remains.

It would be different, if you update some properties of `x` or `y`, then both references the same object with the update.

```js
var x = { a: 'abc', b: 'jkl' };
    y = x;

y = { a: 'pqr', b: 'xyz' };

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```