# CosmosDB stored procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am reading document from collection and storing 2 different variables.
But whenever I remove any key from the JSON it affects first variables result.

I want to keep both of them independent so that change of one will not reflect other.

```
var query =  'SELECT * FROM c where c.id = "XYZ" 

var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery,   
            function (err, documents, responseOptions) 
            {
                if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);  

                if (documents.length != 1) 
                    throw "Document Not Exist"; 
                else
                {
                    var doc1 = new Object;
                    var doc2 = new Object;

                    doc1 =  documents[0];
                    doc2 =  documents[0];
                    var i = doc1.abc[0].pqr;

                    for(x = 0; x < doc1.abc[0].pqr.length; x++)
                    {
                        delete doc1.abc[0].pqr[x];
                    }
                    console.log(doc2)
                }
```

Here console.log(doc2) also not showing the deleted elements which I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc1.abc[0]` and `doc2.abc[0]` represent the same object, they are the same reference.
See [this](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) for some more information on what this means.

If you want to modify the two documents idependently, you need to seperate the data completely.

This is probably the simplest way:

```
 var doc1 =  documents[0];
 var doc2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc1));
```

(Source: [How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference?answertab=votes#tab-top))

Comment: Thanks Alex!!!  var doc1 =  documents[0];
 var doc2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc1)); worked for me.