# Javascript: Why does the '=' operator in object assignment creates a reference to the already existing object?

Tags: javascript, reference, javascript-objects

I was doing the following:

```
let obj = {
    a: 'Hi',
}

let copy = obj;
copy.a = 3;

console.log(obj.a);
```

To my surprise, the value of `obj.a` is also `3`. Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Assignment of object references does not create a copy. That's how the language works; it's fundamental.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive types are passed as value, like Booelan, String, Numbers.

Object types are passed as reference like Array, Function, and Object

You can use Object.assign(), in the docs it states: *The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.*

```js
let obj = {
    a: 'Hi',
}

let copy = Object.assign({},obj);
copy.a = 3;

console.log(obj.a);
```

So in our example {} is our target (an empty object) and our source is the obj variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an Object type to a variable, you're essentially storing what is called a **pointer**. A **pointer** is simply an address in the system memory to where the data for the object is stored.

In your example

```
let obj = { a: 'Hi' } // obj is now pointing to a reference, say, 0x1a, in memory
```

Now when you do

```
let copy = obj // copy is now pointing to the same location in memory, that is, 0x1a
```

In essence `copy` and `obj` are not the data in the object, rather they are an address to the object. The object itself, is some data blob that lives at memory location `0x1a`. Adding/removing/editing properties on either `obj` or `copy`, does nothing other than modify the data that lives at `0x1a`.