# How does JSON.parse() work?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have not worked too much on javascript. And, I need to parse a JSON string. So, I want to know what exactly JSON.parse does. For example :
If I assign a json string to a variable like this,

```
var ab = {"name":"abcd", "details":{"address":"pqrst", "Phone":1234567890}};
```

Now when I print 'ab', I get an object.

Similarly when I do this :

```
var pq = '{"name":"abcd", "details":{"address":"pqrst", "Phone":1234567890}}';
var rs = JSON.parse(pq);
```

The 'rs' is the same object as 'ab'. So what is the difference in two approaches and what does JSON.parse did differently ?

This might be a silly question. But it would be helpful if anybody can explain  this.

Thanks.

Comment: JSON.parse use to convert string to JSON object which is little different than JavaScript object

Comment: This will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I hope below link would help for you!

[click to view right answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object

Comment: Is `JSON.parse(ab);` possibly only a typo? Didn't you wish to write `JSON.parse(pq);` instead?

Comment: yes, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @SarjanDesai—in ECMAScript, there is only one "JSON object", it's defined in [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-json-object). There is no difference between an object created from JSON or an [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-object-initializer) because JSON is based on ECMAScript object literal notation. JSON can't represent all data types or properties of ECMAScript though (e.g. functions), see [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Javascript object is a data type in Javascript - it's have property and value pair  as you define in your first example.

```
var ab = {"name":"abcd", "details":{"address":"pqrst", "Phone":1234567890}};
```

Now What is Json : A JSON string is a data interchange format - it is nothing more than a bunch of characters formatted a particular way (in order for different programs to communicate with each other)

```
var pq = '{"name":"abcd", "details":{"address":"pqrst", "Phone":1234567890}}';
```

so it's is a String With json Format.

and at last `JSON.parse()` Returns the Object corresponding to the given JSON text.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my explanation with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu6k8x8h/1/).

```
//this is already a valid javascript object
//no need for you to use JSON.parse()
var obj1 = {"name":"abcd", "details":"1234"};
console.log(obj1);

//assume you want to pass a json* in your code with an ajax request
//you will receive a string formatted like a javascript object
var str1 = '{"name":"abcd", "details":"1234"}';
console.log(str1);

//in your code you probably want to treat it as an object
//so in order to do so you will use JSON.parse(), which will
//parse the string into a javascript object
var obj2 = JSON.parse(str1);
console.log(obj2);
```

*JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, is a minimal, readable format for structuring data. It is used primarily to transmit data between a server and web application, as an alternative to XML.*

Comment: @Wolf Thanks for noticing. Updated answer and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'ab' variable isn't a string, it is a proper javascript object, since you used the {} around it. If you encased the whole thing in "" then it would be a string and would print out as a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Data Type!! That is the answer.
In this case, *ab* is an **object** while *pq* is a string (vaguely speaking). *Print* is just an operation that displays 'anything' as a string. However, you have to look at the two differently.
String itself is an object which has properties and methods associated with it. In this case, *pq* is like an object which has a value: *{"name":"abcd", "details":{"address":"pqrst", "Phone":1234567890}}* and for example, it has a property called *length* whose value is 66.
But *ab* is an object and you can look at *name* and *details* as its properties.

What JSON.parse() did differently was that, it parsed (converted) that string into an object. Not all strings can be parsed into objects. Try passing *{"name":"abc"* and JSON.parse will throw an exception.

Before parsing, *pq* did not have any property *name*. If you did something like *pq.name*, it'll return you *undefined*. But when you parsed it using JSON.parse() then *rs.name* will return the string "abcd". But *rs* will not have the property *length* anymore because it is not a string. If you tried *rs.length* then you'll get a value undefined.