# Create function which returns a generic JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiples entities and they have the same structure ("entityId" and "name"), like this:

Gender

```
"gender" : {
     genderId: 1,
     name: "someValue"
}
```

EducationLevel

```
"educationLevel" : {
     educationLevelId: 1,
     name: "someValue"
}
```

ProfessionalTitle

```
"professionalTitle" : {
     professionalTitleId: 1,
     name: "someValue"
}
```

I wrote this function to get a generic JSON but of course is wrong. How can I set "field+Id" correctly?

My function

```
function getGenericJson(field, nameValue, idValue){ 
var idName = field + "Id"; 
var fieldJson = { 
name: nameValue, 
field+"Id": idValue 
}
return fieldJson;
```

}

Input example

```
getGenericJson("gender", "someValue", 1);
```

Comment: are you trying to return a json string object?

Comment: @funcoding There is no such thing as "JSON Object" or "JSON String Object". It's either JSON (a String), or an Object. "JSON" stands for "JavaScript Object Notation"

Comment: I think you're wrong! https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: and from another website: JSON objects can be created with JavaScript. Let us see the various ways of creating JSON objects using JavaScript −https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_objects.htm

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong, but I think both of these websites are using the wrong terminology. Saying _JavaScript Object Notation Object_ sounds wrong to me, like saying "ATM machine", which would mean _Automated Teller Machine machine_. [Read this if you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object). Anyway, as long as we understand each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6, you can write it like this:

```
function getGenericJson(field, nameValue, idValue){
  return { 
    name: nameValue, 
    [field+"Id"]: idValue 
  }
}
```

In ES5, you would write it like this:

```
function getGenericJson(field, nameValue, idValue){
  var fieldJson = { 
    name: nameValue
  };

  fieldJson[field + "Id"] = idValue;
  return fieldJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with brackets as follows:

```
var fieldJson = {
    ...,
    [ field + "Id" ]: idValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

**ES5 :**

```js
function getGenericJson(field, nameValue, idValue) { 
    var fieldJson = {}; 
    fieldJson.name = nameValue;
    fieldJson[field+"Id"] = idValue;
    return fieldJson;
};

console.log(getGenericJson("gender", "someValue", 1));
```

**ES6 using backticks(template literals)  :**

```js
function getGenericJson(field, nameValue, idValue) { 
    let fieldJson = {};
    let fieldName = `${field}ID`;
    fieldJson.name = nameValue;
    fieldJson[fieldName] = idValue;
    return fieldJson;
};

console.log(getGenericJson("gender", "someValue", 1));
```