# How to parse JSON in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON array, and what I want is to get the password field alone

```
var user = [ { _id: 5902086ecbc0dd11e4870fd9,
    password: '$2a$08$FIpkmFT1WDZggQYyBA4CVuop6pelbKBfUEJ1/KAVIV2Si9Ho1EYhi',
    email: 'jv100@gmail.com',
    lastName: 'v',
    firstName: 'j',
    updatedDate: 2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z,
    createdDate: 2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z } ]
```

I tried to parse it using this code

```
var obj = JSON.parse(user);
console.log(user.password);
```

but still it is undefined.

Comment: It doesn't need parsing. It's already an array. And since it's an array of objects you'll have to use it like this: `user[ index ].password;` (`user[0].password;` for the first object ...).

Comment: This is not JSON. There's nothing to parse!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Javascript Object and JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: actually that is what I received from my db (I'm using moongose for that), and I dont know how will I get the password field.

thanks for the response, it helps

Comment: Then I don't think you've posted real code. If you are getting data from a database you cannot have a fragment of JavaScript code with an array literal, unless of course your database wrapper decodes it for you. In either case, it's unlikely we can offer help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User is already a list of objects, so you don't need to parse it. However, it is an array. So if you meant for it to be an array, you'd need to access the password by using this code:

```
console.log(user[0].password);
```

Comment: `user` is already an array of objects not JSON. JSON is a string representation of objects.

Comment: yes it solved my problem. sorry for noob question question. Im newby for nodejs. thanks alot

Comment: I fixed my answer to clarify that change @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @PeterLaBanca a response after 4 years, 1 month and 6 days haha. Better late than never :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's already an array there is nothing to parse. You can access your property via :

```
console.log(user[0].password);
```

You can't access your property with `user.password` because `user` variable is not object, it's an array, your object is stored at the zero index of your array.

Answer (score 2):

You already have `JSON object`. hence, no need to parse it again.

**DEMO**

```js
var user = [{ _id: "5902086ecbc0dd11e4870fd9",
    password: '$2a$08$FIpkmFT1WDZggQYyBA4CVuop6pelbKBfUEJ1/KAVIV2Si9Ho1EYhi',
    email: 'jv100@gmail.com',
    lastName: 'v',
    firstName: 'j',
    updatedDate: "2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z",
    createdDate: "2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z" } ];
    
var password = user[0].password;

console.log(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'user' is not a JSON array. It's an array with a single Javascript object as its element. 
JSON.parse(arg) can only be used to parse a JSON string to a plain Javascript object. That being said, to access the javascript object within the array, you can do:

```
var userData = user[0];
```

To access the password within the variable, userData, you can do:

```
var password = userData.password;
```

Log the password to the console with:

```
console.log(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var user = [ {_id:'5902086ecbc0dd11e4870fd9',password: '$2a$08$FIpkmFT1WDZggQYyBA4CVuop6pelbKBfUEJ1/KAVIV2Si9Ho1EYhi',email: 'jv100@gmail.com',lastName: 'v',firstName: 'j',updatedDate: '2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z',createdDate:' 2017-04-27T15:04:14.483Z' } ];

var obj = user[0];
console.log(obj.password);
```