# How does copying a JavaScript object from one array into another array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to copy one *JavaScript* element from an array into another array and then edit some of its properties. the specific code I used was:

```
var friends=[]
var enemies=[
    {
        name: "Slime",
        health: 20,
        attack: 10,
        defense: 15,
        speed: 5,
        drops: {name: "Vial of Blood", chance: 10, type: "consumable", id: 0},
        friendable: {possible: false}
    },
    {
        name: "Bat",
        health: 15,
        attack: 5,
        defense: 10,
        speed: 20,
        drops: {name: "Speedy Vial", chance: 5, type: "consumable", id: 1},
        friendable: {possible: true, item: 0}
    }
]

function dofriend(num11,num12) {
    let protype=enemies[num12]
    sack.splice(num11,1)
    invid.splice(num11,1)
    invtype.splice(num11,1)
    friends.push(protype)
    friends[friends.length-1].drops=protype.name
    friends[friends.length-1].name=prompt("Pick a name for your friend.",protype.name)
    battlechk=false;
    document.getElementById("textbox").innerText="You befriended "+friends[friends.length-1].name+"!"
    document.getElementById("optionbox").innerHTML="<button class=\"option\" onclick=\"cancel()\">Yay!</button>"
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that a new element gets added to the `friends` array that is the same as one of the elements in the `enemies` array. Then the player is allowed to enter a new name for that element in the `friends` array. Since the drops, part of the element is no longer necessary I wanted to replace it with the original name for future use. What actually happens is that both the `enemies` element and the `friends` element get edited to be the same. I don't understand why.

There may be something else happening while I am editing stuff, but that seems unlikely. I have checked and found nothing, but if you want to take a look the full code [can be found here](https://github.com/Fish767/Space-Clones). The files that are being used in this example are `friend.js` and `globalvars.js`. In addition, `battle.js` and `explore.js` are also involved here. `battle.js` leads to `friend.js` being called and then the `friends` array is used in explore.js.

I am interested in knowing how JavaScript elements behave when duplicated and if there is a way to do this without editing the element in the `enemies` array.

**Edit**: Changed every instance of *JSON* to *JavaScript* because I was wrong in thinking that this was *JSON*.

Comment: Have you read about immutable objects in javascript. Since, javascript stores values other than primary datatypes as reference not the copy of the object that you are trying to create, Whenever you try to change something in your copied array it changes the original as well. You could try using spread operator that ES6 comes with and now major browsers also support them.

Comment: @DipeshDulal I have not read about that. I am going to look that up now.

Comment: The question must contain -> `Current Code`, `Current Output`, `Expected Output` and `What you tried`

Comment: With a single line of code, the way you could create copy is by doing `const friends = [ ...enemies ]`.

Comment: @DipeshDulal could I get around that by actually creating a new object that uses the old objects values for its own. For example: {name: prompt(ect), attack: enemies[num12].attack,...}

Comment: You mean object. You have objects in array.

Comment: FYI: It is not JSON.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489783/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-object-and-json-object

Comment: @epascarello What is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript objects cannot be copied. Instead, all would-be-copies link back to the original. You have to hard code a new object with the desired values so that it is not linked to the original object. For example:

```
let f={
     name: "namehere",
     secondAttribute: 0
}
let r={
    name: f.name,
    secondAttribute: f.secondAttribute
}
```

r is not linked to f even though they have the same attributes. You can edit r or f without changing the other.